# How to add namespace to an xml file using java program

Tags: java, xml

I want to add namespace to an xml file using java program.
So how can I add namespace to an xml file using java

Thanks
Bapi

Comment: Similar SO thread [Creating an XML document using namespaces in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528312/creating-an-xml-document-using-namespaces-in-java)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating an XML document using namespaces in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528312/creating-an-xml-document-using-namespaces-in-java)

Answer (score 1):

Whit JDom

add an URI to xmlns in root element

```
Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("yourURI");
Element root = new Element("someName", ns);
```

add any namespace

```
Namespace ns = Namespace.getNamespace("someName", "someValue");
Element yourElement = new Element("someName", ns);
root.addChild(yourElement);
Document doc = new Document(root);
```