# Create XML element with “image:image”

Tags: java, xml

I am using java to create a sitemap xml.

```
Element img = doc.createElement("image:image");
```

I get an exception:

```
org.w3c.dom.DOMException: INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: An invalid or illegal XML character is specified.
```

Any advice on how do I create the element?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use XML-namespaces. See this question for ways how to do it: [Creating an XML document using namespaces in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528312/creating-an-xml-document-using-namespaces-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

in this elemnt name `"image:image"`, this `:` is not a valid cahrecter.

**EDIT**

[Reference link](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_elements.asp)

```
Best Naming Practices for XML Element Name

Make names descriptive. Names with an underscore separator are nice: <first_name>, <last_name>.

Names should be short and simple, like this: <book_title> not like this: <the_title_of_the_book>.

Avoid "-" characters. If you name something "first-name," some software may think you want to subtract name from first.

Avoid "." characters. If you name something "first.name," some software may think that "name" is a property of the object "first."

Avoid ":" characters. Colons are reserved to be used for something called namespaces (more later).

XML documents often have a corresponding database. A good practice is to use the naming rules of your database for the elements in the XML documents.

Non-English letters like éòá are perfectly legal in XML, but watch out for problems if your software vendor doesn't support them.
```