# How to create a XML header?

Tags: java, xml

Please, how can I create an XML header like this one in Java?

```
<cfg:configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-
    instance" xmlns:ContentRouter="http://company/ContentRouter-3.0" 
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cfg="http://company/configuration">.
```

I am using `DocumentBuilderFactory` and my xml looks similar but it is a little bit different..

My code:

```
Element rootElement = doc.createElement("cfg:configuration");
Attr attr1 = doc.createAttribute("xmlns:xsi");
attr1.setValue("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
Attr attr2 = doc.createAttribute("xmlns:ContentRoute");
attr2.setValue("http://eurotel/ContentRouter-3.0");
Attr attr3 = doc.createAttribute("xmlns:xs");
attr3.setValue("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
Attr attr4 = doc.createAttribute("xmlns:cfg");
attr4.setValue("http://eurotel/configuration");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows

```
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.DOMImplementation;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.DOMImplementationLS;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSOutput;
import org.w3c.dom.ls.LSSerializer;

public class RegexTest {
    private static DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        RegexTest domTest = new RegexTest();
        domTest.testXmlDocumentWithNamespaces();
    }

    public void testXmlDocumentWithNamespaces() throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        DOMImplementation domImpl = db.getDOMImplementation();
        Document document = addNameSpaces(domImpl);
        serialize(domImpl, document);
    }

    private Document addNameSpaces(DOMImplementation domImpl) {
        Document document = domImpl.createDocument("http://company/configuration", "cfg:configuration", null);
        document.getDocumentElement().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:ContentRouter", "http://company/ContentRouter-3.0");
        document.getDocumentElement().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xs", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
        document.getDocumentElement().setAttributeNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/xmlns/", "xmlns:xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");

        return document;
    }

    private void serialize(DOMImplementation domImpl, Document document) {
        DOMImplementationLS ls = (DOMImplementationLS) domImpl;
        LSSerializer lss = ls.createLSSerializer();
        LSOutput lso = ls.createLSOutput();
        lso.setByteStream(System.out);
        lss.write(document, lso);
    }

}
```

Prints :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<cfg:configuration xmlns:cfg="http://company/configuration" xmlns:ContentRouter="http://company/ContentRouter-3.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
```

P.S. Reffered [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11133754/adding-namespace-to-an-already-created-xml-document) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/528312/creating-an-xml-document-using-namespaces-in-java)