# how to make gpx file in android

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, dom, gpx

I wanna write gpx file with DOM and Transformer

My code is like that

```
try {
    val document =
      DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().newDocument()
    val trkpt = document.createElement("trkpt")
    trkpt.setAttribute("lat", "-33.626932")
    trkpt.setAttribute("lon", "-33.626932")
    val ele = document.createElement("ele")
    ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode("-6"))
    trkpt.appendChild(ele)
    document.appendChild(trkpt)
    val transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer()
    transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.METHOD,"gpx")

    val saveFolder = File(folderPath) // 저장 경로
    if (!saveFolder.exists()) {       //폴더 없으면 생성
      saveFolder.mkdir()
    }
    val path = "route_${System.currentTimeMillis()}.gpx"
    val file = File(saveFolder, path)         //로컬에 파일저장

    val source = DOMSource(document)
    //val result = StreamResult(FileOutputStream(file))
    val result = StreamResult(System.out)
    transformer.transform(source, result)
    return Uri.fromFile(file)
  }catch(e:Exception){
    e.printStackTrace()
  }
```

the out put is like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><trkpt lat="-33.626932" lon="-33.626932"><ele>-6</ele></trkpt>
```

But I wanna change the  tag to , like this

```
<gpx xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" creator="TraceDeTrail http://www.tracedetrail.fr" version="1.1" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1 http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/gpx.xsd ">
```

How can I edit like this, the attributes as well

the reason why I try to change from JPX to myself, is i need to get time from waypoint.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nPh2s.png)

Sometimes, I need to get time from WayPoint class, but the time's type is ZonedDateTime. but it's not work on SDK 24... is there any solution get time from waypoint?

---

I add the ThreeTenABP, but I don't know how I exactly use this.
I add library on Gradle and init in app-instance
but it still makes an error

```
 wpList.add(
      WayPoint.builder()
        .lat(currentLatLng.latitude)
        .lon(currentLatLng.longitude)
        .name("Start")
        .desc("Start Description")
        .time(System.currentTimeMillis())  <- RunningActivity.kt:107
        .type(START_POINT)
        .build()
    )
```

```
2020-05-06 16:46:16.895 8877-8877/com.umpa2020.tracer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.umpa2020.tracer, PID: 8877
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Ljava/time/Instant;
        at io.jenetics.jpx.WayPoint$Builder.time(WayPoint.java:767)
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.main.start.running.RunningActivity.start(RunningActivity.kt:107)
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.main.start.running.RunningActivity.onSingleClick(RunningActivity.kt:175)
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.util.OnSingleClickListener$DefaultImpls.onClick(OnSingleClickListener.kt:19)
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.main.start.BaseRunningActivity.onClick(BaseRunningActivity.kt:45)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "java.time.Instant" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.umpa2020.tracer-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.umpa2020.tracer-2/lib/x86, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
        at io.jenetics.jpx.WayPoint$Builder.time(WayPoint.java:767) 
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.main.start.running.RunningActivity.start(RunningActivity.kt:107) 
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.main.start.running.RunningActivity.onSingleClick(RunningActivity.kt:175) 
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.util.OnSingleClickListener$DefaultImpls.onClick(OnSingleClickListener.kt:19) 
        at com.umpa2020.tracer.main.start.BaseRunningActivity.onClick(BaseRunningActivity.kt:45) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5610) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:22265) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
```

Answer (score 0):

gpx is a special xml essentially. What you're talking about is the **XML Namespace**.

How to create it: [ho to create XML header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39612625/ho-to-create-xml-header)

A xml file can only have one root element, but there are so many `trkpt` elements in a gpx file. So `trkpt` item should not be a root element. You should include all `trkpt` elements in a single `gpx` element, which is the root element of your gpx file.

To generate a gpx file in Android, the better choice is using a library. Most of them can help you conduct all the above operations.

I'm using `io.jenetics.jpx` in my android project and it works fine.

XML doesn't support appending elements. If you want to generate a gpx file while logging, you should do this in an appendable form, such as any `Serializable` type. After finishing logging you can create a valid GPX file from the Serialization file.

The `WayPoint` in jpx is a Serializable type, I'm using it.

You can also use Android `Location`, which implements `Parcelable`, the android implementation like Serializable.

my code:

```java
public class TrackService extends Service {
    private int notificationId = 142857 ;
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder;
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager;
    private Timer timer = new Timer(true);
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "org.kib.qtp";
    private File serializerFile;
    private ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private Long basetime;
    SimpleDateFormat sdf;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(){
        super.onCreate();
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, new Intent(this, MainActivity.class), 0);
        builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_map_black_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.track))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.tracktext))
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_LOW)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
            startForeground (notificationId, builder.build());
        else
            notificationManager.notify(notificationId, builder.build());
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy(){
        try {
            endTrack();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stopForeground(true);
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
        /**
         * @param ele require altitude or not
         * @param time update time
         * @param fine fine location or not
         * @param name the gpx file's name
         */
        sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", getResources(). getConfiguration().locale);

        int time = 60000;
        boolean ele = false;
        boolean fine = false;
        String name = Calendar.getInstance().getTime().toString().replaceAll(" ", "_");

        if (intent.hasExtra("time"))
            Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).getInt("time");
        if (intent.hasExtra("ele"))
            Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).getBoolean("ele");
        if (intent.hasExtra("fine"))
            Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).getBoolean("fine");
        if (intent.hasExtra("name"))
            Objects.requireNonNull(intent.getExtras()).getString("name");

        File path = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/gpx");
        while(!path.exists())
            path.mkdirs();
        try {
            serializerFile = new File(getFilesDir().getAbsolutePath() + "/gpx/" + name );
            if (serializerFile.exists())
                serializerFile.delete();
            while(!serializerFile.exists())
                serializerFile.createNewFile();
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(serializerFile));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        basetime = 0L;
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_start_tracking, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        startTrack(time, ele, fine);
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private void endTrack() throws IOException {
        timer.cancel();
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(new FileInputStream(serializerFile));
        TrackSegment.Builder segment = TrackSegment.builder();
        while (true) {
            try{
                WayPoint wp = (WayPoint) ois.readObject();
                segment.addPoint(wp);
            } catch (EOFException e) {
                break;
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ignored){

            }
        }
        final GPX gpx = GPX.builder().addTrack(track -> track.addSegment(segment.build())).build();
        GPX.write(gpx, serializerFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".gpx");
        Toast.makeText(this, R.string.toast_gpx_write, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        new File(serializerFile.getAbsolutePath() + ".tobeupload").createNewFile();;
    }

    private void startTrack(int time, boolean ele, boolean fine) {

        TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
            public void run() {
                Location location = getLocation(ele, fine);
                if (location != null){
                    try {
                        if (location.getTime() != basetime){
                            basetime = location.getTime();
                            WayPoint point = WayPoint.builder().lat(location.getLatitude()).lon(location.getLongitude()).ele(location.getAltitude()).time(location.getTime()).build();
                            if (point != null){
                                oos.writeObject(point);
                                NotificationCompat.Builder timerBuilder = builder.setContentText(getString(R.string.tracktext) + sdf.format(location.getTime()));
                                Log.i("track", location.getLatitude() +","+ location.getLongitude() +","+ location.getAltitude());
                                notificationManager.notify(notificationId,timerBuilder.build());
                            }
                        }

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        };  
        timer.schedule(task, 0, time);  
    }

    private Location getLocation(boolean ele, boolean fine) {
        //get location here
    }
}
```

jpx includes zonedDateTime class, which works in java8. But it was backported to Java 6 by its creator, Stephen Colebourne, and also backported to early android version as a library.

Library is here: [JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP - An adaptation of the JSR-310 backport for Android.](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP)

And how to use: [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project - StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project)

Comment: actually i used JPX library. but my app's minimum sdk version is 24. it means I need to use java 7. but the jpx library include zoneddatetime class... it works from java8. so I think I need to create myself... do you know other library??

Comment: jpx works fine in my project, and its min sdk is 21. You can use a Long variable as time. For example location.getTime(). @Yunkwon

Comment: umm.. the reason why I'm changing from jpx to myself is, I need to get time from waypoint... i edit end of my post. plz see and reply.. I need your help...

Comment: OK, I have understood. the java.time.* package in java 8 has been backported to Java 6 by its creator Stephen Colebourne, and also backported to early android version. It's here: github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP

Comment: I have a question again...
I add ThreeTenABP to my project. and also init in my App instance.
but I think it's not work. well how to use it?
I add more information about this on the end of my post

Comment: I think you'd better go to github repository of ThreeTenABP and post an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a bunch of extension functions for the XmlSerializer class to simplify creating GPX files.  No need to install 3rd-party libraries.

Example:

```
import org.xmlpull.v1.XmlSerializer

val xml = Xml.newSerializer()
xml.gpxDocument(stream, context.getString(R.string.app_name))
{
  metaData(name = "filename.gpx", time = now())
  track("Track Name", "Track Type") {
    trackSegment {
      extensions {name("Track Name")}
      trackPoint(lat, long)
      ...
      trackPoint(lat, lon)
    }
  }
}
```

Extension Functions:

```
val fixType = listOf("none", "2d", "3d", "dgps", "pps")

data class Email(val id: String?, val domain: String?, val email: String?)
data class Link(val href: String, val text: String? = null, val type: String? = null)
data class Person(val name: String? = null, val email: Email? = null, val link: Link? = null)
data class Bounds(val minLat: Double, val minLon: Double, val maxLat: Double, val maxLon: Double)

fun XmlSerializer.document(stream: OutputStream,
                           encoding: String = "UTF-8",
                           init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  setOutput(stream, encoding)
  startDocument(encoding, true)
  init()
  endDocument()

}

fun XmlSerializer.gpxDocument(stream: OutputStream,
                              creator: String,
                              version: String = "1.1",
                              encoding: String = "UTF-8",
                              init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  document(stream, encoding)
  {
    element("gpx")
    {
      attribute("xmlns", "http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1")
      attribute("xmlns:xml", "http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace")
      attribute("xmlns:xsd", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema")
      attribute("version", version)
      attribute("creator", creator)
      init()

    }
  }
}

//  element
fun XmlSerializer.element(name: String,
                          nameSpace: String? = null,
                          init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  startTag(nameSpace, name)
  init()
  endTag(nameSpace, name)

}

//  element with attribute & content
fun XmlSerializer.element(name: String,
                          content: String,
                          nameSpace: String? = null,
                          init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  startTag(nameSpace, name)
  init()
  text(content)
  endTag(nameSpace, name)

}

//  element with content
fun XmlSerializer.element(name: String,
                          content: String,
                          nameSpace: String? = null) =
  element(name, nameSpace) {
    text(content)
  }

fun XmlSerializer.attribute(name: String, value: String): XmlSerializer =
  attribute(null, name, value)

fun XmlSerializer.track(name: String? = null,
                        type: String? = null,
                        singleSegment: Boolean = false,
                        init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  element("trk")
  {
    name(name)
    type(type)

    if (singleSegment)
      trackSegment { init() }
    else
      init()
  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.trackSegment(init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  element("trkseg")
  {
    init()
  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.route(name: String? = null,
                        type: String? = null,
                        init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  element("rte")
  {
    name(name)
    type(type)
    init()

  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.extensions(nameSpace: String? = null, init: XmlSerializer.() -> Unit)
{
  element("extensions", nameSpace)
  {
    init()
  }
}

private fun XmlSerializer.point(pointType: String,
                                lat: Double,
                                lon: Double,
                                elevation: Double? = null,
                                geoidHeight: Double? = null,
                                time: Instant? = null,
                                type: String? = null,
                                bearing: Float? = null,
                                speed: Float? = null)
{
  if (lat < -90.0 || lat > 90.0 || lon < -180.0 || lon > 180.0) return

  element(pointType)
  {
    attribute("lat", "$lat")
    attribute("lon", "$lon")
    if (elevation != null) element("ele", "$elevation")
    if (time != null) element("time", "$time")
    if (geoidHeight != null) element("geoidheight", "$geoidHeight")
    type(type)

    if (bearing != null || speed != null)
      extensions {
        if (bearing != null) element("bearing", "$bearing")
        if (speed != null) element("speed", "$speed")

      }
  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.routePoint(lat: Double,
                             lon: Double,
                             elevation: Double? = null,
                             geoidHeight: Double? = null,
                             time: Instant? = null,
                             type: String? = null,
                             bearing: Float? = null,
                             speed: Float? = null) =
  point("rtept", lat, lon, elevation, geoidHeight, time, type, bearing, speed)

fun XmlSerializer.trackPoint(lat: Double,
                             lon: Double,
                             elevation: Double? = null,
                             geoidHeight: Double? = null,
                             time: Instant? = null,
                             type: String? = null,
                             bearing: Float? = null,
                             speed: Float? = null) =
  point("trkpt", lat, lon, elevation, geoidHeight, time, type, bearing, speed)

fun XmlSerializer.wayPoint(lat: Double,
                           lon: Double,
                           elevation: Double? = null,
                           geoidHeight: Double? = null,
                           time: Instant? = null,
                           type: String? = null,
                           bearing: Float? = null,
                           speed: Float? = null) =
  point("wpt", lat, lon, elevation, geoidHeight, time, type, bearing, speed)

fun XmlSerializer.metaData(name: String? = null,
                           description: String? = null,
                           author: Person? = null,
                           copyright: String? = null,
                           link: Link? = null,
                           time: Instant? = null,
                           keywords: String? = null,
                           bounds: Bounds? = null)
{
  element("metadata") {
    name(name)
    description(description)
    author(author)
    copyright(copyright)
    link(link)
    time(time)
    keywords(keywords)
    bounds(bounds)

  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.bounds(bounds: Bounds?)
{
  if (bounds != null)
    element("Bounds") {
      attribute("minlat", bounds.minLat.toString())
      attribute("minlon", bounds.minLon.toString())
      attribute("maxlat", bounds.maxLat.toString())
      attribute("maxlon", bounds.maxLon.toString())

    }
}

fun XmlSerializer.keywords(keywords: String?)
{
  if (keywords != null) element("keywords", "$keywords")
}

fun XmlSerializer.time(time: Instant?)
{
  if (time != null) element("time", "$time")
}

fun XmlSerializer.copyright(copyright: String?)
{
  if (copyright != null) element("copyright", copyright)
}

fun XmlSerializer.name(name: String?)
{
  if (name != null) element("name", name)
}

fun XmlSerializer.type(type: String?)
{
  if (type != null) element("type", type)
}

fun XmlSerializer.description(description: String?)
{
  if (description != null) element("description", description)
}

fun XmlSerializer.author(author: Person?)
{
  if (author != null)
  {
    name(name)
    email(author.email)
    link(author.link)
  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.link(link: Link?)
{
  if (link != null)
  {
    element("link") {
      attribute("href", link.href)
      if (link.text != null) element("text", link.text)
      type(link.type)
    }
  }
}

fun XmlSerializer.fix(fix: String?)
{
  if (!fixType.contains(fix)) return
  if (fix != null) element("fix", fix)

}

fun XmlSerializer.email(email: Email?)
{
  if (email != null)
  {
    var id = email.id ?: ""
    var domain = email.domain ?: ""

    if (email.id == null && email.email != null) id = email.email.substringBefore("@")
    if (email.domain == null && email.email != null) domain = email.email.substringAfter("@")

    if (id != "" && domain != "")
      element("email") {
        attribute("id", id)
        attribute("domain", domain)
      }
  }
}
```

This work is based on

1. [www.schibsted.pl/blog/back-end/readable-xml-kotlin-extensions/](https://www.schibsted.pl/blog/back-end/readable-xml-kotlin-extensions/)
2. [medium.com/android-news/how-to-generate-xml-with-kotlin-extension-functions-and-lambdas-in-android-app-976229f1e4d8](https://medium.com/android-news/how-to-generate-xml-with-kotlin-extension-functions-and-lambdas-in-android-app-976229f1e4d8)
3. [gist.github.com/Audhil/cf9844def5ad9e4210985d2080a101f0](https://gist.github.com/Audhil/cf9844def5ad9e4210985d2080a101f0)

I haven't implemented all GPX fields, but they can easily be added.  Here is a [link](https://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1/) to the latest GPX schema.

You can find my latest version of these extension functions on [GitHub](https://gist.github.com/oliverClimbs).