# Convert String XML fragment to Document Node in Java

Tags: java, xml, string

In Java how can you convert a String that represents a fragment of XML for insertion into an XML document?

e.g.

```
String newNode =  "<node>value</node>"; // Convert this to XML
```

Then insert this node into an **org.w3c.dom.Document** as the child of a given node?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7607435/363573

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I parse a HTML string in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497946/how-can-i-parse-a-html-string-in-java)

Comment: @Suma That question is about HTML, this is about XML.

Answer (score 67):

```
Element node =  DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream("<node>value</node>".getBytes()))
    .getDocumentElement();
```

Comment: the .parse( new StringInputStream(....

should read

.parse( new ByteArrayInputStream( new String( "xml" ).getBytes() ) );

Comment: I just hate these commentboxes and their lack of markup ( or markdown, for that matter)

Comment: but this does not copy the children...

for example if you do this in case of
"<tag1><tag2><tag3>blah </tag3> blah</tag2></tag1>

It only gets <tag1> without its children

Comment: This didn't work for me because it didn't copy children as noted by grobartn. @McDowell's solution did work.

Answer (score 33):

You can use the document's *[import](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean))* (or *[adopt](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#adoptNode(org.w3c.dom.Node))*) method to add XML fragments:

```
  /**
   * @param docBuilder
   *          the parser
   * @param parent
   *          node to add fragment to
   * @param fragment
   *          a well formed XML fragment
   */
  public static void appendXmlFragment(
      DocumentBuilder docBuilder, Node parent,
      String fragment) throws IOException, SAXException {
    Document doc = parent.getOwnerDocument();
    Node fragmentNode = docBuilder.parse(
        new InputSource(new StringReader(fragment)))
        .getDocumentElement();
    fragmentNode = doc.importNode(fragmentNode, true);
    parent.appendChild(fragmentNode);
  }
```

Comment: Hmm. If this is the simplest solution, I must say it's rather complicated for such a small problem.

Comment: I've pared it down to the minimum - it still uses what you get in the JRE API, though, so a bit of verbosity is unavoidable.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for.  I didn't realize that I had to import the fragment into the dom before appending it to the parent node!

Comment: If verbosity you not want, you must not use Java, Luke. Thanks for the answer, no chance for anyone to figure that out.

Comment: Althoug the selected answer is correct given what the user asked, this anser is 'more' correct.

Comment: Cheers @McDowell! Your solution is still saving the day, even in 2019...

Answer (score 15):

For what it's worth, here's a solution I came up with using the [**dom4j**](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) library. (I did check that it works.)

Read the XML fragment into a `org.dom4j.Document` (note: all the XML classes used below are from org.dom4j; see Appendix):

```
  String newNode = "<node>value</node>"; // Convert this to XML
  SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
  Document newNodeDocument = reader.read(new StringReader(newNode));
```

Then get the Document into which the new node is inserted, and the parent Element (to be) from it. (Your org.w3c.dom.Document would need to be converted to org.dom4j.Document here.) For testing purposes, I created one like this:

```
    Document originalDoc = 
      new SAXReader().read(new StringReader("<root><given></given></root>"));
    Element givenNode = originalDoc.getRootElement().element("given");
```

Adding the new child element is very simple:

```
    givenNode.add(newNodeDocument.getRootElement());
```

Done. Outputting `originalDoc` now yields:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<root>
    <given>
        <node>value</node>
    </given>
</root>
```

**Appendix**: Because your question talks about `org.w3c.dom.Document`, here's how to convert between that and `org.dom4j.Document`.

```
// dom4j -> w3c
DOMWriter writer = new DOMWriter();
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = writer.write(dom4jDoc);

// w3c -> dom4j
DOMReader reader = new DOMReader();
Document dom4jDoc = reader.read(w3cDoc);
```

(If you'd need both kind of `Document`s regularly, it might make sense to put these in neat utility methods, maybe in a class called `XMLUtils` or something like that.)

Maybe there are better ways to do this, even without any 3rd party libraries. But out of the solutions presented so far, in my view this is the easiest way, even if you need to do the dom4j <-> w3c conversions.

**Update** (2011): before adding dom4j dependency to your code, note that [it is *not* an actively maintained project, and has some other problems too](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831865/what-java-xml-library-do-you-recommend-to-replace-dom4j). Improved version 2.0 has been in the works for ages, but there's only an alpha version available. You may want to consider an alternative, like XOM, instead; read more in the question linked above.

Comment: If dom4j is a NO-GO, try this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7607435/363573

Comment: Latest dom4j release is April 2020 at time of writing. The project is still getting development.

Answer (score 6):

Here's yet another solution, using the [**XOM** library](http://www.xom.nu/), that competes with [my dom4j answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729621/convert-string-xml-fragment-to-document-node-in-java/729979#729979). (This is part of my [quest to find a good dom4j replacement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/831865/what-java-xml-library-do-you-recommend-to-replace-dom4j) where XOM was suggested as one option.)

First read the XML fragment into a `nu.xom.Document`:

```
String newNode = "<node>value</node>"; // Convert this to XML
Document newNodeDocument = new Builder().build(newNode, "");
```

Then, get the Document and the Node under which the fragment is added. Again, for testing purposes I'll create the Document from a string:

```
Document originalDoc = new Builder().build("<root><given></given></root>", "");
Element givenNode = originalDoc.getRootElement().getFirstChildElement("given");
```

Now, adding the child node is simple, and similar as with dom4j (except that XOM doesn't let you add the original root element which already belongs to `newNodeDocument`):

```
givenNode.appendChild(newNodeDocument.getRootElement().copy());
```

Outputting the document yields the correct result XML (and is remarkably easy with XOM: just print the string returned by `originalDoc.toXML()`):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root><given><node>value</node></given></root>
```

(If you wanted to format the XML nicely (with indentations and linefeeds), use a [`Serializer`](http://xom.nu/apidocs/nu/xom/Serializer.html); thanks to Peter Štibraný for pointing this out.)

So, admittedly this isn't very different from the dom4j solution. :) However, XOM may be a little nicer to work with, because the API is better documented, and because of its design philosophy that there's one canonical way for doing each thing.

**Appendix**: Again, here's how to convert between `org.w3c.dom.Document` and `nu.xom.Document`. Use the helper methods in XOM's `DOMConverter` class:

```
// w3c -> xom
Document xomDoc = DOMConverter.convert(w3cDoc);

// xom -> w3c
org.w3c.dom.Document w3cDoc = DOMConverter.convert(xomDoc, domImplementation);  
// You can get a DOMImplementation instance e.g. from DOMImplementationRegistry
```

Comment: Note that instead of new Builder().build(new StringReader("<root><given></given></root>")); you can also use new Builder().build("<root><given></given></root>", "test.xml"); (where "test.xml" is some random base URI)

Comment: "If you wanted to format the XML nicely (with indentations and linefeeds), I'm not sure how to do that with XOM." -- using Serializer class. Configure it using setIndent and setMaxLength, and call write(document).

Comment: Serializer is also easy to customize by subclassing.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't really understand what exactly is the meaning of the baseURI param; passing an empty string also works, so I'm using that. In any case, that does simplify the code somewhat. For formatting, Serializer indeed works fine.

Comment: I think baseURI would be used for resolving relative references to DTD or XInclude (http://lists.ibiblio.org/pipermail/xom-interest/2004-November/001498.html)

Answer (score 6):

```
/**
*
* Convert a string to a Document Object
*
* @param xml The xml to convert
* @return A document Object
* @throws IOException
* @throws SAXException
* @throws ParserConfigurationException
*/
public static Document string2Document(String xml) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {

    if (xml == null)
    return null;

    return inputStream2Document(new ByteArrayInputStream(xml.getBytes()));

}


/**
* Convert an inputStream to a Document Object
* @param inputStream The inputstream to convert
* @return a Document Object
* @throws IOException
* @throws SAXException
* @throws ParserConfigurationException
*/
public static Document inputStream2Document(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException, SAXException, ParserConfigurationException {
    DocumentBuilderFactory newInstance = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    newInstance.setNamespaceAware(true);
    Document parse = newInstance.newDocumentBuilder().parse(inputStream);
    return parse;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you're using dom4j, you can just do:

Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(text);

(dom4j now found here:  https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j)

Comment: Just went to their web site. They place Google Ads right into the typical Maven-generated navigation bar! Incredible!

Comment: Apparently, the site is no longer operated by the dom4j guys, but some domain grabbers took over...

Answer (score 1):

...and if you're using purely XOM, something like this:

```
    String xml = "<fakeRoot>" + xml + "</fakeRoot>";
    Document doc = new Builder( false ).build( xml, null );
    Nodes children = doc.getRootElement().removeChildren();
    for( int ix = 0; ix < children.size(); ix++ ) {
        otherDocumentElement.appendChild( children.get( ix ) );
    }
```

XOM uses fakeRoot internally to do pretty much the same, so it should be safe, if not exactly elegant.

Answer (score 1):

Try [jcabi-xml](http://xml.jcabi.com), with a one liner:

```
Node node = new XMLDocument("<node>value</node>").node();
```

Comment: jcabi-xml build error ```Unresolved references to [com.jcabi.xml] by class(es) on the Bundle-Classpath[Jar:dot]```