# How can I parse a HTML string in Java?

Tags: java, html, parsing

Given the string `"<table><tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr></table>"`, what is the (easiest) way to get a [DOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) Element representing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found this somewhere (don't remember where):

```
 public static DocumentFragment parseXml(Document doc, String fragment)
 {
    // Wrap the fragment in an arbitrary element.
    fragment = "<fragment>"+fragment+"</fragment>";
    try
    {
        // Create a DOM builder and parse the fragment.
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document d = factory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(
                new InputSource(new StringReader(fragment)));

        // Import the nodes of the new document into doc so that they
        // will be compatible with doc.
        Node node = doc.importNode(d.getDocumentElement(), true);

        // Create the document fragment node to hold the new nodes.
        DocumentFragment docfrag = doc.createDocumentFragment();

        // Move the nodes into the fragment.
        while (node.hasChildNodes())
        {
            docfrag.appendChild(node.removeChild(node.getFirstChild()));
        }
        // Return the fragment.
        return docfrag;
    }
    catch (SAXException e)
    {
        // A parsing error occurred; the XML input is not valid.
    }
    catch (ParserConfigurationException e)
    {
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 13):

If you have a string which contains HTML you can use [Jsoup](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-document-from-string) library like this to get HTML elements:

```
String htmlTable= "<table><tr><td>Hello World!</td></tr></table>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlTable);

// then use something like this to get your element:
Elements tds = doc.getElementsByTag("td");

// tds will contain this one element: <td>Hello World!</td>
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 10):

Here's a way:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.*;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.*;

public class HtmlParseDemo {
   public static void main(String [] args) throws Exception {
       Reader reader = new StringReader("<table><tr><td>Hello</td><td>World!</td></tr></table>");
       HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
       parser.parse(reader, new HTMLTableParser(), true);
       reader.close();
   }
}

class HTMLTableParser extends HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback {

    private boolean encounteredATableRow = false;

    public void handleText(char[] data, int pos) {
        if(encounteredATableRow) System.out.println(new String(data));
    }

    public void handleStartTag(HTML.Tag t, MutableAttributeSet a, int pos) {
        if(t == HTML.Tag.TR) encounteredATableRow = true;
    }

    public void handleEndTag(HTML.Tag t, int pos) {
        if(t == HTML.Tag.TR) encounteredATableRow = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I want to put all the data pieces into an array in the outer class, rather than print them out?

Comment: @Imray, go right ahead, you have my permission to put them in some sort of collection instead of printing them :)

Comment: I put them in a collection inside the `HTMLTableParser` class, and then created a getter method to get them. Is that the best way to do it?

Comment: @BartKiers how is it related to topic question?? The question is "to get a DOM Element representing it", not to catch SAX events!

Answer (score 5):

you could use HTML Parser, which a Java library used to parse HTML in either a linear or nested fashion.
It is an open source tool and can be found on SourceForge

Answer (score 3):

[You could use Swing:](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=31059&seqNum=1)

> How do you make use of the
>   HTML-processing capabilities that are
>   built into Java? You may not know that
>   Swing contains all the classes
>   necessary to parse HTML. Jeff Heaton
>   shows you how.

Answer (score 3):

I've used [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) it's OSS, detects(forgives) badly formatted tags and is lightweight

Answer (score 0):

One can use some of the `javax.swing.text.html` utility classes for parsing HTML.

```java
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringReader;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument;
import javax.swing.text.html.HTMLEditorKit;
import javax.swing.text.html.parser.ParserDelegator;
//...
try {
    String htmlString = "<html><head><title>Example Title</title></head><body>Some text...</body></html>";
    HTMLEditorKit htmlEditKit = new HTMLEditorKit();
    HTMLDocument htmlDocument = (HTMLDocument) htmlEditKit.createDefaultDocument();
    HTMLEditorKit.Parser parser = new ParserDelegator();
    parser.parse(new StringReader(htmlString),
            htmlDocument.getReader(0), true);
    // Use HTMLDocument here
    System.out.println(htmlDocument.getProperty("title")); // Example Title
} catch(IOException e){
    //Handle
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

See:

- [`HTMLDocument`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLDocument.html)
- [`HTMLEditorKit`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.html)