# How to read and manipulate a HTML document exported from Microsoft Word?

Tags: java, ms-word, html-parsing

I have a Microsoft Word Doc that was saved as a .htm web page.  Below is the code I have.  My question is how can I get the text from the document, and append it to a string.  I noticed that the paragraph is set to a tag `<p class=MsoNormal>` so any suggestions.  The string I want to append it to is documentText

```
    String documentText = "";
    FileInputStream fileInput = null;
    BufferedInputStream myBuffer = null;
    DataInputStream dataInput = null;
    fileInput = new FileInputStream(selectedFile);
    myBuffer = new BufferedInputStream(fileInput);
    dataInput = new DataInputStream(myBuffer);
    while (dataInput.available() != 0){
        System.out.println(dataInput.readLine());
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at libraries such as [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) and [Jericho HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html) or use the native [HTMLEditorKit.Parser](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.Parser.html) + [HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/html/HTMLEditorKit.ParserCallback.html) approach suggested on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1498008/664577).

Comment: So in the example what is the fragment getting passed in in the answer.  I am a desktop and app developer.  Not much of a web dev.

Comment: This API is actually from Swing :D. Bart Kiers is creating a `StringReader` from a fixed html fragment on the main method and printing every `TR` (table row) tag encountered. You can do something similar using any other kind of Reader (e.g., a `BufferedReader` pointing to your external file) and tag (say a `<p>` tag).

Comment: Ohh ok cool, what if I wanted to read in all the tags and do some string manipulation and write the html file back out?

Comment: Then I would again suggest a more advanced library such as Jericho. Take a look at the Sample Programs at the web page linked in my answer. Download the library and play around.

Answer (score 2):

Use a HTML Parser library, such as [HTML Parser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/).

Comment: Mark, sorry for the straightness, but given your question, yes it is. Take your time to study the libraries suggest by galuano1 and me and do your own research, stackoverflow is not a replacement for Google. When you have something more concrete to ask (which means code that actually do some parsing) people will be able to help you further.

Comment: I understand that but Anthony Accioly actually pointed torwards a example.  Not looking for someone to do it for me.