# Getting the value of an input tag with a specific ID using regex

Tags: java, regex

I have following html content part, and I want to get the value

```
-7326630261683062897:1196341531039871985
```

from all http content. There is only one unique point that is id `javax.faces.ViewState`.

How can I get the value? What kind of regex do I have to use?

```
<input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="javax.faces.ViewState" 
value="-7326630261683062897:1196341531039871985" autocomplete="off" />
```

Comment: Read [How can I parse a HTML string in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1497946/how-can-i-parse-a-html-string-in-java)

Comment: I would caution you against using regex for any HTML tag. Considering you're using Java, there's probably already a parser for HTML. Check out the link above

Answer (score 0):

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("value=\"(-)*[\\d]+:[\\d]+\"");
Matcher m = p.matcher(html);
while(m.matches()){
    String s = m.group();
    s = s.subString(7, s.size()-2);
}
```

At the point after the substring call, s should contain just what you want.

Comment: where to use id="javax.faces.ViewState". There are many value="" statements in html content

Comment: Use a parser if you want all the values. It will do a much better job and less head ache for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex:

```
id="javax\.faces\.ViewState".*value="(.*?)"
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/vL6zW8/1)**

```
MATCH 1
1.  [84-124]    `-7326630261683062897:1196341531039871985`
```