# How to create a XML object from String in Java?

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, jdom

I am trying to write a code that helps me to create a XML object. For example, I will give a string as input to a function and it will return me a XMLObject.

```
XMLObject convertToXML(String s) {}
```

When I was searching on the net, generally I saw examples about creating XML documents. So all the things I saw about creating an XML and write on to a file and create the file. But I have done something like that:

```
Document document = new Document();
Element child = new Element("snmp");
child.addContent(new Element("snmpType").setText("snmpget"));
child.addContent(new Element("IpAdress").setText("127.0.0.1"));
child.addContent(new Element("OID").setText("1.3.6.1.2.1.1.3.0"));
document.setContent(child);
```

Do you think it is enough to create an XML object? and also can you please help me how to get data from XML? For example, how can I get the `IpAdress`from that XML?

Thank you all a lot

**EDIT 1:** Actually now I thought that maybe it would be much easier for me to have a file like `base.xml`, I will write all basic things into that for example:

```
<snmp>
<snmpType><snmpType>
<OID></OID>
</snmp>
```

and then use this file to create a XML object. What do you think about that?

Comment: give the fully qualified name (FQN) of XMLObject. Are you using xmlbeans?

Comment: Ok, first question: What is `XMLObject`? Which library is that?

Comment: XMLObject is just an example, I want a function that gets a string as a parameter and then it will return a XML object . I am using jdom for implementation.

Comment: What do you want to do with XMLObject once you have it? If you just want a representation that you can manipulate in code and navigate through, then Document/Element are probably good enough.

Comment: @Richard I will create XML objects and will send them through sockets and then I will get the informations that are written in XML. Do you think Document/Element is enough ?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

If you can create a string xml you can easily transform it to the xml document object  e.g. -

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><a><b></b><c></c></a>";  

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();  
DocumentBuilder builder;  
try {  
    builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();  
    Document document = builder.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(xmlString)));  
} catch (Exception e) {  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

You can use the document object and xml parsing libraries or xpath to get back the ip address.

Comment: as I understand "parse" returns a DOM document object, what will you do to get a SAX version of this code? thanx!

Comment: What if there is no source, and we want to create a new Document object and then append children to it , Is it possible or do we have to create  the root Element first?

Comment: just copy-pasted and spent a pair of minutes to check because I used wrong imports to go too fast, double check, correct imports are: import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;

Answer (score 11):

try something like

```
public static Document loadXML(String xml) throws Exception
{
   DocumentBuilderFactory fctr = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
   DocumentBuilder bldr = fctr.newDocumentBuilder();
   InputSource insrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
   return bldr.parse(insrc);
}
```