# How to Get data from soap response using java

Tags: java, xml, cdata

Here I have sample code getting response from Webservice.
I have given input like this :

```
String values = Bham.getBDetails("xxxxxxxxx");
```

Here Response in soap UI Look Like :

```
           <GetxxxxxhDetailsResponse >
         <GetxxxxxhDetailsResult><![CDATA[<xxxxxFAMILY>
          <FAMILYDETAIL>
               <xxxx_ID>11111</2_ID>
               <ID>50218036</ID>
               <NAME>???? ????</NAME>
              <FATHERNAME>????????</FATHERNAME>
          </FAMILYDETAIL>
          <FAMILYDETAIL>
                <xxxx_ID>2222</2222_ID>
                <ID>91622649</ID>
               <NAME>????</NAME>
              <FATHERNAME>?????</FATHERNAME>
             </FAMILYDETAIL>
            </xxxxxHFAMILY>]]>
      </GetxxxxxhDetailsResult>
      </GetxxxxxhDetailsResponse>
```

Here in response CDATA is there so, I am getting out in my console like this :

```
           <xxxxFAMILY>
               <FAMILYDETAIL>
             <xxxxx_ID>9999-PXFR-00159</xxxxx_ID>
            <ID>50218036</ID>
           <NAME>???? ????</NAME>
          <FATHERNAME>????????</FATHERNAME>
         <DOB>01/01/1984</DOB>
         <GENDER>?????</GENDER>
       <MARITALSTATUS>???????</MARITALSTATUS>
     <MOTHERNAME>????</MOTHERNAME>
    <RELATIONSHIPWITHHOF>?????</RELATIONSHIPWITHHOF>
    <SPOUSENAME>?????</SPOUSENAME>
   </FAMILYDETAIL>
    <FAMILYDETAIL>
        <xxxxx_ID>9999-PXFR-00159</xxxxx_ID>
          <ID>91622649</ID>
       <NAME>????</NAME>
      <FATHERNAME>?????</FATHERNAME>
     <DOB>01/01/2007</DOB>
     <GENDER>?????</GENDER>
    <MARITALSTATUS>????????</MARITALSTATUS>
      <MOTHERNAME>????</MOTHERNAME>
    <RELATIONSHIPWITHHOF>??????</RELATIONSHIPWITHHOF>
    <SPOUSENAME />
   </FAMILYDETAIL>
  </xxxxxFAMILY>
```

So here I  want to get xxxx_ID, ID all properties. Can you Please suggest me?

Comment: Build a xml object from the string as suggested in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Read the XML into a Document and use either Xpath or document navigation to fetch the node values you are after.

Viral Patel has a tutorial on xpath and java, but there are plenty of others.

http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

From the little you are posting, you need to read the string from the details entity and build a XML document from that. Read the blog I posted or this answer [How to create a XML object from String in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7607327/how-to-create-a-xml-object-from-string-in-java)

This should get you going.

```
public static List<String> getIdFromXml(String xml) {
    Document xmlDoc = loadXML(xml);
    NodeList nodeList = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("ID");
    List<String>ids = new ArrayList<String>(nodeList.getLength());
    for(int i=0;i<nodeList.getLength(); i++) {
        Node x = nodeList.item(i);
        ids.add(x.getNodeValue());
    }

    return ids;
}

public static Document loadXML(String xml) throws Exception
{
    DocumentBuilderFactory fctr = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder bldr = fctr.newDocumentBuilder();
    InputSource insrc = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
    return bldr.parse(insrc);
}
```

Comment: what is returning string format? maybe you should update your post with something you already tried.

Comment: i am getting stuck in CDATA...if i follow this link but note getting anything ....@thst

Comment: Here  String values = bham.getDetails("xxxxxx");

Comment: if i pass like this ,i am getting <FAMILYDETAIL>
             <xxxx_ID>11111</2_ID>
            <ID>50218036</ID>
            <NAME>???? ????</NAME>
           <FATHERNAME>????????</FATHERNAME>
        </FAMILYDETAIL>
        <FAMILYDETAIL>
           <xxxx_ID>2222</2222_ID>
          <ID>91622649</ID>
            <NAME>????</NAME>
        <FATHERNAME>?????</FATHERNAME>
         </FAMILYDETAIL>

Comment: so here i want to get xxx_id and all

Comment: Update your question and post a code sample there. otherwise I cannot help you.