# xml string parse in android

Tags: android, xml, parsing

I am new xml parsing in android. The below is the xml string I have. I am getting this XML string data from onActivityResult method.So the below data saved in one string variable like resultText; I want to read each attribute values from below string.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<PrintLetterBarcodeData uid="521007171049" 
name="Bandigari Katamaraju"
 gender="M"
 yob="1991" 
 co="S/O: BANDIGARI YADAGIRI" 
 house="4-141/1"
 loc="EDULLAGUDEM" 
 vtc="Edullagudam"
 dist="Nalgonda"
 subdist="For New VTC"
 state="Andhra Pradesh" 
 pc="508112"/>
```

I want to read the each attribute of that single node. Thanks in advance.

Comment: checkout this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7607445/2674225 You can parse it to `Node` and get attributes (http://developer.android.com/reference/org/w3c/dom/Node.html#getAttributes()).

Or you can simply split it and read attributes manually, but it's less elegant ;)

Comment: Thanks for reply, but I didn't get you. I want to read each attribute value. The code you referred is not exactly belongs to the same. How can I achieve this by split?

Comment: When you parse this xm to Node, you will be able to get all this node attibutes via method `getAttributes()`, which will return them as `NamedNodeMap` object. You have to know, that everythinh is a node - even attibutes are nodes. And you have all of them it this returned object. Then you can simple iterate over it ex. in `for` loop and you can access attribute by  `obj.item(i)` and call, ex. `getNodeName()` or `getNodeValue()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an `XMLParser` (check [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/xml.html)), one that works nicely is the [XmlPullParser](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html).

You can initialize your parser with:

```
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( "<foo>Hello World!</foo>" ) );
```

Than you can iterate over the complete `XML` object using

```java
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    /*YOUR CODE HERE*/
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
```

Where you can check for the `eventTypes` : `START_DOCUMENT`, `START_TAG`, `END_TAG`, and `TEXT`.
Once you are in either start or end tag you can get the name of the tag using `getName()`, at the `TEXT` event type you can use `getText()` and you can use, at the `BEGIN_TAG`, the functions `getAttributeCount()`, `getAttributeName(index)` and `getAttributeValue()` you can get all the attributes belonging to each tag.

---

**In your specific case**

You can use something like this:

```java
String xmlString = YOURSTRING_HERE;
XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();
xpp.setInput( new StringReader ( xmlString ) );
int eventType = xpp.getEventType();
while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
    if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {
        System.out.println("Start document");
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
        System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
        if (xpp.getName().equals("PrintLetterBarcodeData")){
            for (int i=0; i<xpp.getAttributeCount(); i++){
                 System.out.println("attribute:"+xpp.getAttributeName(i)+" with value: "+xpp.getAttributeValue(i))
                 //Store here your values in the variables of your choice.
            }
        }
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
        System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
    } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {
        System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
    }
    eventType = xpp.next();
}
System.out.println("End document");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. You saved my time. Working superb as I expected.