# How to convert a string to a xml in java?

Tags: java, xml, string

I have a string object  "hello world"
I need to create an xml file from this string with hello world as text content.
I tried the following code snippet

```
String xmlString = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"></soap:Envelope>";

    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();   

    DocumentBuilder builder;   
    try  
    {   
        builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();   

        // Use String reader   
        Document document = builder.parse( new InputSource(   
                new StringReader( xmlString) ) );   

        TransformerFactory tranFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();   
        Transformer aTransformer = tranFactory.newTransformer();   
        Source src = new DOMSource( document );   
        Result dest = new StreamResult( new File("D:\\myXML.xml" ) );   
        aTransformer.transform( src, dest );  

    } catch (Exception e)   
    {   
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block   
        e.printStackTrace();   
    }
```

this code works fine. but when i replace the string with "Hello world" its not working.
Can any one help me out in this ?
Thanks

Comment: How is it not working? Do you get an error? Wrong output?

Comment: [Fatal Error] :1:1: Content is not allowed in prolog. org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: Content is not allowed in prolog. at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) at com.metlife.ins.portal.idi.enrollment.gsi.vo.IDIEnrollmentBO.createXMLResponse(IDIEnrollmentBO.java:74) at com.metlife.ins.portal.idi.enrollment.gsi.vo.IDIEnrollmentBO.main(IDIEnrollmentBO.java:107) i am getting this error when i change to Hello World or some other normal string

Comment: Try passing the string in bytes by using getBytes() of String class.. Hopefully that will work..

Comment: Which string are you replacing with "hello world"?

Comment: What will be your XML root node ? You may place `Hello World` as text content of some node.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/729621/convert-string-xml-fragment-to-document-node-in-java?rq=1

Comment: i am initialising the xmlString with hello world instead of the existing formatted xml string

Comment: That wont work. "hello world" would need to be placed inside a xml node. Like `<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\"><text>hello world</text></soap:Envelope>` or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error is because you are trying to parse `xmlString` as a valid XML string, which it is not. For example, your code will run fine with the following `xmlString`:

```
String xmlString = "<hi>Hello World</hi>";
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot turn the string "hello world" into XML, as it is not a valid xml document. It has no declaration, and no tags.

The code above will not turn text into xml objects, it will only take a string which is already valid xml and write it out to file.

To be honest, if you just want to write it to a file, the xml stuff is all unnecessary.

If you want some kind of "hello world" xml file, you'll need to add the declaration and some tags yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `String newNode =  "<node>Hello World</node>";`

You can use

```
 Element node =  DocumentBuilderFactory
    .newInstance()
    .newDocumentBuilder()
    .parse(new ByteArrayInputStream(newNode.getBytes()))
    .getDocumentElement();
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution can be here is:
If it's a valid string(correct as per XML norms) just write it into a new file using FileWriter and give it .xml extension.
Anyway it will not convert if it's not a valid XML string