# Android - How to handle Webservice in XML?

Tags: android, xml, web-services

I have a sample XML file as below:

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
  <h:html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:jr="http://openrosa.org/javarosa" xmlns:orx="http://openrosa.org/xforms/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <h:head>
<h:title>tutorial</h:title>
<model>
  <instance>
    <tutorial id="tutorial">
      <name/>
      <age/>
      <gender/>
      <photo/>
      <date/>
      <location/>
      <thanks/>
      <start/>
      <end/>
      <today/>
      <deviceid/>
      <subscriberid/>
      <simserial/>
      <phonenumber/>
      <meta>
        <instanceID/>
      </meta>
    </tutorial>
  </instance>
  <bind nodeset="/tutorial/name" required="true()" type="string"/>
  <bind constraint=". &gt; 0 and . &lt; 120" jr:constraintMsg="That's not a valid age!" nodeset="/tutorial/age" required="true()" type="int"/>
  <bind nodeset="/tutorial/gender" type="select1"/>
  <bind nodeset="/tutorial/photo" type="binary"/>
  <bind nodeset="/tutorial/date" type="date"/>
  <bind nodeset="/tutorial/location" type="geopoint"/>
  <bind nodeset="/tutorial/thanks" readonly="true()" type="string"/>
  <bind jr:preload="timestamp" jr:preloadParams="start" nodeset="/tutorial/start" type="dateTime"/>
  <bind jr:preload="timestamp" jr:preloadParams="end" nodeset="/tutorial/end" type="dateTime"/>
  <bind jr:preload="date" jr:preloadParams="today" nodeset="/tutorial/today" type="date"/>
  <bind jr:preload="property" jr:preloadParams="deviceid" nodeset="/tutorial/deviceid" type="string"/>
  <bind jr:preload="property" jr:preloadParams="subscriberid" nodeset="/tutorial/subscriberid" type="string"/>
  <bind jr:preload="property" jr:preloadParams="deviceid" nodeset="/tutorial/simserial" type="string"/>
  <bind jr:preload="property" jr:preloadParams="phonenumber" nodeset="/tutorial/phonenumber" type="string"/>
  <bind calculate="concat('uuid:', uuid())" nodeset="/tutorial/meta/instanceID" readonly="true()" type="string"/>
</model>
</h:head>
<h:body>
<input ref="/tutorial/name">
  <label>What's your name?</label>
</input>
<input ref="/tutorial/age">
  <label>How old are you?</label>
</input>
<select1 ref="/tutorial/gender">
  <label>Gender</label>
  <item>
    <label>Male</label>
    <value>male</value>
  </item>
  <item>
    <label>Female</label>
    <value>female</value>
  </item>
</select1>
<upload mediatype="image/*" ref="/tutorial/photo">
  <label>Please Take a picture</label>
</upload>
<input ref="/tutorial/date">
  <label>Date</label>
</input>
<input ref="/tutorial/location">
  <label>Where are you?</label>
  <hint>You need to be outside for your GPS to work.</hint>
</input>
<input ref="/tutorial/thanks">
  <label>Thanks for your time <output value="/tutorial/name"/>!</label>
</input>
</h:body>
</h:html>
```

Now i want to fill `<input ref="/tutorial/name">` with the data coming as a response from the web service? I have a web service which is giving the response correctly. Please help me....

Comment: The question seems like a basic parse, process and reply. You will need to provide more detail about your problem before anyone can help.

Comment: What is the format you are receiving the response in?<br/> If it is just one value to pick from the response and place in the xml then you are good to go with string functions by picking up the tag index and getting substring as value and doing the same in xml file and replacing. If it is more than one value than you can go with xml parsers, using DOM parser like dom4j http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/. If the response is in json then use Google Gson library http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Replace `<input ref="/tutorial/name">` tag. You have to follow this three steps.

1) Find `<input ref="/tutorial/name">` TAG in the XML file.

2) Do update, delete , replace whatever functionality you want.

3) Write the content into the XML file

**Step 1: Find Node:**

```
DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = factory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document dom = db.parse(FILE);
Element root = dom.getDocumentElement();

//get node-list,
NodeList inputNodeList = root.getElementsByTagName("input");

//iterate over all input node to find the desired one.
for(int i=0;i<inputNodeList.length();i++){
  Node inputNode = inputNodeList.item(i); //get a single node.
  String refStr = inputNode.getAttributes().getNamedItem("ref").getNodeValue();
  if(refStr.compareTo("/tutorial/name")==0){

     // Bingo, You have find the NODE. Now you can do any operations like delete, edit whatever you want.
   }
}
```

**Step 2 : Do Replace operation.**

you can delete the node using.

```
inputNode.getParentNode().removeChild(inputNode);
```

If you want to replace the node, have look at [replaceChild()](http://www.androidjavadoc.com/m5-rc15/android/xml/dom/InnerNodeImpl.html#replaceChild%28org.w3c.dom.Node,%20org.w3c.dom.Node%29) method.

Basic idea is,

- **Create a Node from the response string**. Refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/729621/convert-string-xml-fragment-to-document-node-in-java) for creating xml node from the string.
- **Find parent of the inputNode using inputNode.getParentNode()**.
- **Use replaceChild() method to replace old node with the new node**.

For an example of replaceChild() method you can refer [this link](http://www.w3schools.com/dom/dom_nodes_replace.asp).
Here is a nice tutorial for modifying XML file using DOM parser - [TUTORIAL](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-modify-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/).

**Step 3 : Write the content into the XML file.**

```
TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();  
Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();   
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);   
StreamResult result = new StreamResult(selectedFile); 
transformer.transform(source, result);
```

Hope, this will give you some hint about achieving your desired task.

Answer (score 4):

I am using SAXParser to handle the xml parsing in my app.

```
try {
        /**
         * Create a new instance of the SAX parser
         **/
        SAXParserFactory saxPF = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser saxP = saxPF.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xmlR = saxP.getXMLReader();
        URL url = new URL("http:Your URL"); // URL of the XML
        XMLHandler myXMLHandler = new XMLHandler();
        xmlR.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);
        xmlR.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Also here is a good tutorial on this: http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-build-a-simple-sax-parser/