# How to read this xml?

Tags: java, xml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to read an XML file with Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333479/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-java)

CLOSED

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files/7373596#7373596) you can find a complete SAX example. Ignore the DTD if you do not want to use it.

Answer (score 0):

There's only one element with `grantee-template` tag name. You seem to expect two. What you are really look for is its two children.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first statement

```
NodeList granteeTemplate = doc.getElementsByTagName("grantee-template")
```

with

```
NodeList granteeTemplate=doc.getDocumentElement().getChildNodes();
```