# How to keep the sql queries out of the java code

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I've written a small code which functions like follows:

1. Read an input file
2. Read the first line in it and check if it
   has value `AAA` at a certain position
3. if it satisfies the
   condition call the method `insertAAAmethod` and load the data to the
   oracle table
4. read the next line if it is record `BBB` call the `insertBBBrmethod` which has   different insert query

The problem is I have 15 different records in the input file so I have 15 different methods like `insertAAAmethod` each with different insert query:

```
public static void insertAAARecord() throws Exception {

    String sqlQuery = "insert into my_table(ColumnA,ColumnB,ColumnC,ColumnD,ColumnE,ColumnF,ColumnG)"
            + "values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

    try {

        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlQuery);

        pstmt.setString(1, "AAA");
        pstmt.setDate(2,
                StringtoDate("AAA", CurrentLine.substring(150, 158)));
        pstmt.setDate(3,
                StringtoDate("AAA", CurrentLine.substring(158, 166)));
        pstmt.setString(4, CurrentLine.substring(24, 34));
        pstmt.setString(5, CurrentLine.substring(37, 45));
        pstmt.setString(6, CurrentLine.substring(147, 150));
        pstmt.setDate(7, headerDate);

        pstmt.executeUpdate();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace(System.out);

    } finally {

        pstmt.close();

    }

}
```

Is it possible to keep the sql query out of the java code? (Like in a properties file, for example)

**Note:** The insert query changes as per the record if it is record 'AAA' it should follow one insert query if the record is different insert query should change..

Let me know how to optimize my code.

Comment: can you add some examples of those SQL queries? you say they are different but not how much...

Comment: Why not store this metadata in the database?

Comment: I'm a big fan of JPA but in this case and with the little information we have I would not recommend it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should create a properties file with all your queries and load them on startup using Properties object, then use the Properties to look them up.  You can also you Spring to inject the queries into your configuration objects.

I have always built DB object that integrate your code to DB data and queries are kept there, it is much easier to debug and manage as everything you need is in one place.

Make your life simple, avoid ORMs and tune your SQL queries (or let DBAs do that that's what they do and they are good at it).  However if you do not like SQL or don't care how efficient it is, then ORM like Hibernate may be what you need.

Comment: Use a static block to load the properties file and assign each SQL query from it to a static member variable.

Comment: +1: this is the only answer that do not think ORM is the only solution to this kind of problems.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will take more time than other approaches, but it would help you with your code optimization.

Every query/process have common attributes.

- SQL Query
- String pattern
- Parameters

and each parameter has

- Position
- Datatype
- etc

If you're using spring already, you'll be able to define these as beans in your config.xml.
if not, you can use xml configuration anyway (instead of property files)

Then, you will have to create some class to parse these beans and create the custom queries.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer..I am not using spring. Could you forward any link or tutorial on how to use xml configuration instead of property files.. Thanks so much

Comment: There are several ways to do that, in this link are interesting options, let me know if you need any further help. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333479/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333479/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-java)

Answer (score 0):

Try to use any ORM framework like Hibernate/JPA, Ibatis?

Answer (score 0):

You want to use JPA.  I would recommend walking through a simple JPA tutorial such as the following: http://glassfish.java.net/javaee5/persistence/persistence-example.html

That tutorial will demonstrate the basics of how to create or modify objects and persist those changes in a database.  Good luck.