# How to split a string (with params) in Java

Tags: java, regex, xml, string

I have a string that alternates between text and chapter marks. I'd like to have it in a key-value-array where the key is the chapter name and the value is the chapter content. The text looks like this:

```
<chapter name="First chapter" />
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr.
<chapter name="Second chapter" />
Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et.
<chapter name="Third chapter" />
Dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.
```

The resulting array is supposed to look like this:

```
[
  {"First chapter", "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr."},
  {"Second chapter", "Sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et."},
  {"Third chapter", "Dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua."}
]
```

How can I do this?

Comment: Please provide your tried code.

Comment: this code doesn't clear anyone what you exactly want to do.. so please post your all tried code... Thank You

Comment: This might help you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333479/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @devd with [this posting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333479/how-to-read-an-xml-file-with-java), the solution to the above case is XPath. There is an [example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13844988/3164889).

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular expression to locate subject and content. Your case is very suitable for that.
The link below has a summary for regex in java.
http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaRegularExpressions/article.html

Comment: DO. NOT. USE. REGEX. TO. PARSE. XML.

Comment: @JimGarrison Why not?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454