# Delete content in XML file in the code

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm developing an android application, and I would like to delete a small content in my XML file in my application's code.
I would like to delete the content below:

```
<pma:structure_schemas>
    <pma:database name="test" collation="latin1_swedish_ci" charset="latin1">
        <pma:table name="agenda">
            CREATE TABLE `agenda` (
              `id` int(2) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
              `title` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
              `description` varchar(1000) NOT NULL,
              `town` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
               PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
            ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
        </pma:table>
    </pma:database>
</pma:structure_schemas>
```

Do you have any idea about how to do ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.*;
import org.w3c.dom.*;

public class DeleteXmlNode {

    public static void deleteNode(String nodedetailsExpression) {//Use your expression here depending upon the node you wnt to delete

        try{
        XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expression = xpath.compile(nodedetailsExpression);
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        Document document = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder().parse(new File("test.xml"));
        Node node = (Node) expression.evaluate(document, XPathConstants.NODE);
        node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(new DOMSource(document), new StreamResult(System.out));
        }catch(Exception e){
        //Do your Exception handling over here.
    }

}
```

Here you need to pass the expression string of the node to be deleted.

Comment: i'm a newcomer in the android programation. I'll try to make some researches about what you posted.

Comment: Ok. Please try and let me know in case of any issue.

Comment: Ok. In my Sax program, to get my xml file, i use this line :
url = new URL("internet adress/xml.xml");
Then, i would like to directly make disapear the XML content i showed to you in my post.
I'm trying to understand what you sent, but i don't really know how to use it effectively.
Do you have something that is easier for me ? 
Thank you a lot for your answer

Comment: i do think so but i hope that it won't be too complicated for me.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2523381/best-java-xml-parser-to-manipulate-edit-an-existing-xml-document). This is a very popular question, for next time google problems before asking here.

Comment: i'm already using the sax parser to do this job. the problem is that certain tags block the using of the feed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code to remove an element with [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sf.net). Notice it is a lot more terse and efficent than DOM

```
import com.ximpleware.*;
import java.io.*;

public class removeElement {
    public static void main(String s[]) throws VTDException,IOException{
        VTDGen vg = new VTDGen();
        if (!vg.parseFile("input.xml", false))
            return;
        VTDNav vn = vg.getNav();
        XMLModifier xm = new XMLModifier(vn);
        AutoPilot ap = new AutoPilot(vn);
        ap.selectXPath("/ClOrdIDS/ClOrdID[@id='3']");
        int i=0;
        while((i=ap.evalXPath())!=-1){
            xm.remove();
        }
        xm.output("output.xml");
    }
}
```