# How to parse this XML using Java

Tags: java, android, xml, parsing

```
<tickettypes>
    <eventid>8</eventid>
    <eventname>air</eventname>
    <tablename>tbl_tickets</tablename>
    <ticketid>1</ticketid>
    <name>Platinum</name>
    <price>200.00</price>
    <printable>Y</printable>
    <ticketid>2</ticketid>
    <name>Gold</name>
    <price>150.00</price>
    <printable>Y</printable>
    <ticketid>3</ticketid>
    <name>Silver</name>
    <price>100.00</price>
    <printable>Y</printable>
    <ticketid>4</ticketid>
    <name>Test</name>
    <price>50.00</price>
    <printable>Y</printable>
     <surveys>
    <surveyid>0</surveyid>
    <surveyname>No Survey entered</surveyname>
    <surveyid>1</surveyid>
    <surveyname>Advertisement</surveyname>
    <surveyid>2</surveyid>
    <surveyname>Friends</surveyname>
    <surveyid>3</surveyid>
    <surveyname>Web Reference</surveyname>
    <surveyid>4</surveyid>
    <surveyname>News Paper</surveyname>
    <surveyid>5</surveyid>
    <surveyname>portals</surveyname>
    </surveys>
</tickettypes>
```

can any one please help me how to parse the following xml file

Comment: Can you please show it in a proper xml format?

Comment: More detail, please. What do you want to do with this file?

Comment: I get this as response from browser. that why i need help

Comment: Java is not an acronym and should not be capitalized.

Comment: As @Mudassir says, please read about SAX. I think it's the easiest approach.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are quite a few examples of this online; the first page of a Google search "parse xml in java" was filled with examples.

http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152

http://www.totheriver.com/learn/xml/xmltutorial.html

http://www.developerfusion.com/code/2064/a-simple-way-to-read-an-xml-file-in-java/

Answer (score 2):

The best way to read XML in Android is to use the [Simple XML Framework](http://simple.sourceforge.net/home.php). If you want a step by step guide then you should take a look at [the blog post on the topic that I wrote](http://robertmassaioli.wordpress.com/2011/04/21/simple-xml-in-android-1-5-and-up/). If you knew simple then this would take you all of ten minutes to write the code that can parse it.