# Yahoo Finance Stream Parsing to insert into MySQL database

Tags: java, mysql, string, parsing, html-parsing

I'm using the Yahoo Finance Streaming API to get stock quotes, I wanted to save these into a DB table for historical reference.

I'm looking for something which can easily parse various strings which have a format that varies like the examples below:

```
<script>try{parent.yfs_mktmcb({"unixtime":1310957222});}catch(e){}</script>   
<script>try{parent.yfs_u1f({"ASX.AX":{c10:"-0.06"}});}catch(e){}</script>
<script>try{parent.yfs_u1f({"AWC.AX":{l10:"2.16",c10:"+0.01",p20:"+0.47"}});}catch(e){}</script>
<script>try{parent.yfs_u1f({"ALZ.AX":{l10:"2.6900",c10:"-0.1200",p20:"-4.27"}});}catch(e){}</script>
```

I want to parse these strings to a MySQL database and I was thinking the easiest way will be using Java to do this parsing. Basically these entries are line by line in a text file. I want to extract the time, the stock code, the price and the change values in a simple table.

The table looks like `StockCode | Date | Time | Price | ChangeDol | ChangePer`

Are there any tools or frameworks which would make this process easy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't how you get your quote, but if you could use YQL, any XML parser would do:

[YQL](http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.quotes%20where%20symbol%20in%20%28%22YHOO%22,%22AAPL%22,%22GOOG%22,%22MSFT%22%29%0A%09%09&env=http://datatables.org/alltables.env)

```
<quote symbol="YHOO">
    <Ask>14.76</Ask>
    <AverageDailyVolume>28463800</AverageDailyVolume>
    <Bid>14.51</Bid>
    <AskRealtime>14.76</AskRealtime>
    <BidRealtime>14.51</BidRealtime>
    <BookValue>9.826</BookValue>
    <Change_PercentChange>0.00 - 0.00%</Change_PercentChange>
    ....
</quote>
```

[List of XML Parsers for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a look there 
http://www.wikijava.org/wiki/Downloading_stock_market_quotes_from_Yahoo!_finance

They get finencial data as csv from yahoo.