# parsing XML to java using xstream

Tags: java, xml, xstream

I am trying to parse xml to java classes, can any one help me.
Thank you.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<patterns>
<pattern if="menuCondition">
    <input>Menu</input>
    <output>
        <command if="taxCondition">Company</command>
        <command>Tax</command>
        <command>Customer</command>
        <command>Vendor</command>
        <command>Banking</command>
        <command>Reports</command>
        <command>Settings</command>
        <command>Logout</command>
    </output>
</pattern>
</patterns>
```

Comment: paste the parsing code that you have at the moment and ask a specific question.

Comment: If you are using xstream, have a look at the tutorials at http://xstream.codehaus.org/ to get started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please have a look at this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java). It has an armada of good answers on Java and XML.