# XML parsing using java

Tags: java, xml-parsing

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body><getSessionId xmlns="http://treecorp.corp:8080/MEENH/service">
<multiRef xmlns:apachesoap="http://xml.apache.org/xml-soap"
xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/"
xsi:type="apachesoap:Map">
<item>
    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">Application</key>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">MobileDevice</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">Version</key>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">1.0</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">Username</key>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">ramau</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">token</key>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string"></value>
</item>
<item>
    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">sessionID</key>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">SESSIONID</value>
</item>
<item>
    <key xsi:type="soapenc:string">OSInformation</key>
    <value xsi:type="soapenc:string">windowsXP</value>
</item>
</multiRef>
</getSessionId>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

This is my XML.

I want to parse this XML using Java and retreive a value based on the key . You can see in the XML there are lot of Key Value Pairs .

For Example if If I want to retrive value for Application I should get the value as MobileDevice.
Like this kindly anyone help me to sort this issue.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2):

There is another similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java).

I personally used [XOM](http://www.xom.nu/) and liked it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the DOM, like shown here: http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=152 for example.

Answer (score 0):

Since its a soap response, why don't you write a nice simple web service client to retrieve the response and automatically turn it into objects for you.

There's an example of that [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayn.html#bnayx).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DSM](https://mfatihercik.github.io/dsm) stream parsing library to convert key-value pair to List then get what you want.

This is the first approach. To do this you should define your yaml mapping file as follows.

```
result:
  type: array     # result is array
  path: /.+item   # read item tag. the path is a regex.
  fields:
    key:
    value:
```

Java Code to parse XML:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML).create();
List<Map<String, Object>> itemList =  (List<Map<String, Object>>)dsm.toObject(xmlFileContent);
```

Here is **itemList** list that converted to json.

```
[ {
  "key" : "Application",
  "value" : "MobileDevice"
}, {
  "key" : "Version",
  "value" : "1.0"
}, {
  "key" : "Username",
  "value" : "ramau"
}, {
  "key" : "token",
  "value" : null
}, {
  "key" : "sessionID",
  "value" : "SESSIONID"
}, {
  "key" : "OSInformation",
  "value" : "windowsXP"
} ]
```

The second approach is converting XML to a **java map** that it's **key** of map is **value of key tag** and **value** of the map is the **value of the *value*** tag in XML.

Here is Mapping File:

```
result:
  type: object     # result is map
  path: /.+multiRef # path is regex
  fields:
    key:
      path: item/key # read value of /.+multiRef/item/key tag
    value:
      path: item/value # read value of /.+multiRef/item/value tag
    application:
      parentPath: item  # assign default value when /.+multiRef/item tag is closed
      default: $self.data.value  # get value of value field.
      filter: $self.data.key=='Application' # assign if key filed is 'Application'
    version:
      parentPath: item
      default: $self.data.value
      filter: $self.data.key=='Version'
    username:
      parentPath: item
      default: $self.data.value
      filter: $self.data.key=='Username'
    token:
      parentPath: item
      default: $self.data.value
      filter: $self.data.key=='token'
    sessionID:
      parentPath: item
      default: $self.data.value
      filter: $self.data.key=='sessionID'
    OSInformation:
      parentPath: item
      default: $self.data.value
      filter: $self.data.key=='OSInformation'
```

Java Code to parse XML:

```
DSM dsm=new DSMBuilder(new File("path/to/mapping.yaml")).setType(DSMBuilder.TYPE.XML).create();
Map<String, Object> result =  (Map<String, Object>)dsm.toObject(xmlFileContent);

String application=result.get("application").toString()
```

Here is the JSON representation of Result:

```
{
  "key" : "OSInformation",
  "value" : "windowsXP",
  "application" : "MobileDevice",
  "version" : "1.0",
  "username" : "ramau",
  "token" : null,
  "sessionID" : "SESSIONID",
  "OSInformation" : "windowsXP"
}
```

**In first it's come a bit complicated but if you look at docs it is very easy.**