# How to parse and modify an xml tag

Tags: xml, linux

I have an xml message in which i need to parse and find a particular tag.  On that tag data I need to check if all the mandatory data elements are present or not.  If a data element is missing i need to add the missing data to the tag.  Once enriched i need to resubmit for further processing.  Can some one give a few guidelines as to how this can be done using linux scripting.  Could the awk command be used to find the tag in the xml message.

Comment: awk is more so used for processing textual table data. Using something like Perl might make your life easier - it has many libraries to deal with XML.

Answer (score 0):

Processing XML using text processing tools like awk will not scale.  Multiple lline data, encoded data etc will make it difficult to handle even small data.  Use XML processing library  - [perl has many](http://cpan.perl.org/authors/id/E/EI/EISEN/perl-xml-modules.html).  All other languages too.

SO questions 
[Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend [XSLT](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt). See also the [Wikipedia article about XSLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSLT), there are some samples. I think XSLT is great for the job you describe.