# Regular Expression too hungry

Tags: java, regex

I'm looking for a regular expression, but can't find.

Parsing a text file looking like that

```
    <resource name="/_op_sox/Project/Default/ICDocumentation/Evaluation/Allianz/Allianz SE/Eval_01241.txt"
              inheritAcls="true">
        <bundle name="AZEvaluation">
            <property name="End Date">
            </property>
            <property name="Evaluation Type">
                <propertyValue name="RCSA"/>
            </property>
        </bundle>
    </resource>
    <resource name="/_op_sox/Project/Default/ICDocumentation/Evaluation/Allianz/Allianz SE/Eval_01481.txt"
              inheritAcls="true">
        <bundle name="AZEvaluation">
            <property name="End Date">
            </property>
            <property name="Evaluation Type">
                <propertyValue name="TRA"/>
            </property>
        </bundle>
    </resource>
   <resource name="/_op_sox/Project/Default/ICDocumentation/Evaluation/Allianz/Allianz SE/Eval_01362.txt"
              inheritAcls="true">
        <bundle name="AZEvaluation">
            <property name="End Date">
            </property>
            <property name="Evaluation Type">
                <propertyValue name="RCSA"/>
            </property>
        </bundle>
    </resource>
```

My current regex matches to much.

```
<resource.+?<propertyValue name="RCSA".+?</resource>
```

It matches the first resource tag and the second + third.
Can somebody change the regex that it really stops at the first `</resource>`

I use this Java code

```
Pattern.compile("<resource.+?<propertyValue name=\"RCSA\".+?</resource>",Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Use an XML parser.

Comment: Simple question - why are you not using XML tools for this ? regexp isn't good over XML or HTML

Comment: Why not use Jsoup?  It would be trivial to find the first `resource` element.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you are not using an XML parser and XPath for that matter?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Yes it is. Using Regex for doing some search and replace over a 200MB Textfile is fast written without the overhead of implementing a SAX Parser. DOM Parser is not working because of memory usage. So my question was not "Who can I solve my problem with XML Parser?", it was how can I change the regex that it does what I like ;)

Comment: I got it... `<resource(?:(?!<propertyValue).)+<propertyValue name="RCSA"(?:(?!<resource).)+</resource>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with this Expression: `<resource(?:(?!<propertyValue).)+<propertyValue name="RCSA"(?:(?!<resource).)+</resource>` but it's to slow.
So I looked a bit around what else can be done in Java and found an easy and fast solution.

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<resource name=.+?</resource>",
            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    String in = getStringFromFile(path, name, pre, count);
    System.out.println("Länge: " + in.length());
    Matcher m = p.matcher(in);
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    int c = 0;
    while (m.find()) {
        m.appendReplacement(sb, getReplacementStage1(m, c++));
    }
    m.appendTail(sb);
    writeStringToFile(path, name, pre, count, sb.toString());
```

So first I use an easier and faster RegEx and then instead of using String.replaceAll I use the matcher to have the chance to calculate the replacement for every find.

```
private static String getReplacementStage1(Matcher m, int c) {
    Pattern p1 = Pattern.compile(
            "<resource[^>]*?contentType=\"Evaluation\"", Pattern.MULTILINE
                    | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m1 = p1.matcher(m.group());
    if (!m1.find()) {
        // remove
        return "";
    }
    Pattern p2 = Pattern.compile("<propertyValue name=\"(?:RCSA|TRA)\"",
            Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL);
    Matcher m2 = p2.matcher(m.group());
    if (m2.find()) {
        // remove
        return "";
    }
    // no change, return the group
    return m.group();
}
```

So may be this solution helps somebody with a similar problem, that don't likes/needs an XML parser...

Answer (score 0):

As Mr E points out, this is not the best way to read data from an XML file at all. Not to mention if you suddenly have to deal with nested elements! However, this will match the name attribute of the propertyValue inside a resource.

```
<resource.+?<propertyValue name=(["'])([^"']*)\1.+?</resource>
```

Comment: I don't need the content of the name attribute. I want to replace the whole resource element if the name attribute of the property value is RCSA.

Comment: Ah I see, in any case, consider using an XML parser and go traverse through the children. Even if you get it working this way it isn't a long term solution and is doomed to fail on some XML files eventually.

Comment: The XML File is 200MB large. It has a lot of different Tags, that i have not mentioned here. So fare a used 5 different regex to reduce the file or change some content. Writing an XML Parse will take me hours...

Comment: Luckily it's been done before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: Tempted to down-vote just for mentioning any option other than "use an xml parser" :)

Comment: Consider even the slightest change, say they have a space between the `/` or something, then you'd need a more complicated regex. Definitely leave it to the parsers for this.