# java- processing xml and modifying it to create new xml

Tags: java, xml, parsing

In a java app that I am working on, there is a need to take an existing XML, then make changes to that xml and give the original as well as new xml, as output.

Which parser do you recommend, such that it uses least memory? Where I can  do the following--

(a) easily take one portion of the xml, and insert it into another place in the same XML?

(b) change some attributes in a section of the xml.

Comment: Have you considered XSLT processing with apache xalan?

Comment: XSLT is _intended_ for what you describe. Java is a general-purpose language.  XSLT will be MUCH easier, and you can even invoke the XSL from Java.

Answer (score 1):

If the document is huge you can take a look at SAX, otherwise just use a DOM parser like [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) for exemple.

With any DOM parser you can copy a node and attach it elsewhere in the document tree.

For exemple using dom4j you can use [`Element.createCopy`](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/apidocs/org/dom4j/Element.html#createCopy%28%29) to copy an element, and add it elsewhere.

Comment: But surely as stated in the comments upper, if you can avoid Java, then use XSLT for such a task

Answer (score 0):

Here's a huge list of Java Parsers for you to choose from. Most of them have the capability to do what you need - XML Parsing, Selecting/Filtering/Copying/Moving Nodes, Modifying Attributes, XML File Read/Write Capabilities, etc. Each has its own advantages disadvantages - the main choosing criteria being Speed and Performance:

[JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)                                 
[XMLBeans](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/)                             
[Xerces](http://xml.apache.org/xerces-j/)                               
[Apache Betwixt](http://commons.apache.org/betwixt/)                       
[XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/)                              
[StAX](http://stax.codehaus.org/)                                 
[JAXB](https://jaxb.dev.java.net/)                                 
[XP Parser](http://www.jclark.com/xml/xp/index.html)                            
[kXML](http://kobjects.org/kxml/index.php)                                 
[JiBX: Binding XML to Java Code](http://jibx.sourceforge.net/)      
[woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/)                            
[VTD-XML 1.5](http://vtd-xml.sf.net)                         
[Zeus](http://zeus.objectweb.org/)                                
[Skaringa](http://skaringa.sourceforge.net/)                            
[Lycia](http://code.google.com/p/lycia/)                               
[Piccolo XML Parser](http://piccolo.sourceforge.net/)                  
[NanoXML](http://nanoxml.cyberelf.be/)                             
[NekoPull](http://www.apache.org/~andyc/neko/doc/pull/index.html)                            
[XOM](http://www.cafeconleche.org/XOM/)                                 
[dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/guide.html)                               
[Jakarta Commons Digester](http://jakarta.apache.org/commons/digester/)            
[JOX](http://www.wutka.com/jox.html)                                 
[KBML](http://koala.ilog.fr/kbml/)                                
[X2JB](http://x2jb.sourceforge.net/)                                
[Staxmate](http://staxmate.codehaus.org/)

Ref1: http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-parsers

Ref2: [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

Comment: I am looking for a parser that uses least memory- processing time is not so much a factor but memory usage is most important- which ones do you suggest for my scenario? Thanks...