# Store XML values to a String in JAVA

Tags: java, xml, arrays, hashmap

I want to store the values contained in an XML file to a java String Object. 
Here is my XML code :

```
<properties>
  <comment>test.xml</comment>
  <entry key="1">test1</entry>
  <entry key="2">test1,test2,test3</entry>
  <entry key="3">test1,test2,test3</entry>
<properties>
```

I want 'values' to be stored in a string.
Eg:

```
String msg;
if(msg.equals("1")){
  String str1 = //get values of key "1" (ie) test1
}
else if(msg.equals("2")){
  String str2 = //get values of key "2" (ie) test1,test2,test3
}
```

Is there any way to do it using HashMap or anything?? 
Thanks.

Comment: An XML-parser comes to mind. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: Use Jaxb http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Java XML properties file. If so, you can load it straight into a [Properties](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html) object by calling [`properties.loadFromXML`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html#loadFromXML%28java.io.InputStream%29).

```
Properties prop = new Properties();
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("props.xml");
prop.loadFromXML(fis);
System.out.println("Value of key 1 is: " + prop.getProperty("1")); //prints test1
```

Note that for this to work, The XML document must have the following `DOCTYPE` declaration:

```
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPATH for it, for instance, it will look like this:

//properties/entry[@key ='1']/text()

Answer (score 0):

The following link will give you the smallest of xml parsing code to perform your task, [XML parsing in Java via Groovy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12690794/xml-parsing-in-java-via-groovy)