# Hashmap - single key, multiple values - How to retrieve?

Tags: java, xml, hashmap, multivalue

I am calling a service and I get the XML response in the below format.

How do I retrieve multiple values under a single key from this response?
I want to store all the values in a `List<String>`

```
<p700:item xmlns:p700="http://abc.test.com">
    <p700:key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key1</p700:key>
    <p700:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value1</p700:value>
    <p700:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value2</p700:value>
    <p700:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value3</p700:value>
    <p700:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value14</p700:value>
</p700:item>
<p700:item xmlns:p700="http://abc.test.com">
    <p700:key xsi:type="xsd:string">Key1</p700:key>
    <p700:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value1</p700:value>
    <p700:value xsi:type="xsd:string">Value2</p700:value>
</p700:item>
```

Comment: Create a `Map<String,List<String>>`.

Comment: Was that your query more about parsing such a XML response? If you have webservice (codefirst) you would have had defined request/response data structure as pojos.I guess you should be getting list of item objects,  but parsing could be bit trickier as it has attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guava has a [`Multimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) interface and a [`ListMultimap`](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn/tags/release03/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html) implementation, which is a map of keys to multiple values contained in a list structure (as opposed to a set or sorted set). It's essentially a `Map<K, Collection<V>>`. You can also find examples [here](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained#Multimap). As for actually parsing the XML, there are a number of questions about that here on SO, and you can start with [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using guava in my project now.

Answer (score 1):

Create a map `String` <-> `List<String>`:

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<...>();
```

Use this code to add values:

```
List<String> values = map.get( key );
if( null == values ) {
    values = new ArrayList<String>();
    map.put( key, values );
}

values.add( "xxx" );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the map and add them manually to a list if you don't want to make the `Map<String, List<String>>` mentioned in the comments under your question.

```
List<String> theList = new ArrayList<String>();
String theKey = "The Key";
for(Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    if(entry.getKey().equals(theKey)) {
        theList.add(entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

This of course assumes you've already extracted the data from the XLS into a `Map<String, String>`.  If you haven't, that's another matter entirely.

If you need a package to ingest your XLS, consider [JXLS](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/sf/jxls/jxls-core/0.9.5/jxls-core-0.9.5-javadoc.jar!/net/sf/jxls/transformer/XLSTransformer.html).