# Java regex extract data between a href tags

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to extract data between a href tags in a Java string. I can
acheive this with replace all and substring and with using indexOf etc.

I would like to know how can I get data using regex.

So basically i am trying to extract data and store in a string or in a list.

```
String data ="12345";
        String sampleStr ="";
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
         data+=i;
        sampleStr += "<a href=\"javascript:yyy_getDetail(\'"+data+"\')\">"+data+"</a>"+", ";
        }           

        System.out.println(sampleStr);
        String temp = sampleStr.substring(sampleStr.indexOf("\">")+2);
```

Any suggestion in regard will be appreciated. What should be regex, so i only extract data.

Comment: Have you tried parsing the HTML to a DOM using an HTML parser?

Comment: Here's a regex to start with: `/<a[^>]*>(.*?)<\/a>/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example for your needs. Note, that the full match will contain the string with anchor tags and your searched content is in the `group 1`.

```
String data ="12345";
String sampleStr ="";
for(int i=0; i<10; i++) 
{
 data+=i;
 sampleStr += "<a href=\"javascript:yyy_getDetail(\'"+data+"\')\">"+data+"</a>"+", ";
} 

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("<a[^>]*>(.*?)</a>");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(sampleStr );
while (matcher.find()) 
{
        System.out.println("Result "+ matcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: @Nomad sorry, you should pass the whole searching string. try my edit

Comment: thanks works like a charm. Can you explain the group part. You mentioned I only need group(1)?

Comment: @Nomad matching group is the part of the whole match which is enclosed in round brackets in my pattern there is one group. But you could change it to "<a[^>]*>(.*?)(</a>)" so there are 2 matching groups now and calling matcher.group(2) will return "</a>". group(0) will return the whole match

Answer (score 1):

Please, use a HTML/XML parser instead. Your life would be much easier.

HTML is usually very inconsistent and you can't be sure that it will turn out the way you want it.

There's actually a famous answer regarding this, at [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags#1732454)

You should take a look at [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) for your options if you choose to use a HTML/XML parser :)

Comment: I'd upvote you, but you don't have a link to a java html parser he could use.

Comment: Added a link for him to take a look there. I'm not really experienced with Java XML parsers so I believe that question should be better :)

Comment: Thanks Spencer and wei2912