# How to create temp table in Java and insert xml data in it

Tags: java, oracle, plsql

I have multiple questions one obviously is the design concern. I have explained the design I came up with for the customer requirements and i'm having some implementation challenges.

Server : OracleE Linux 
Database : Oracle 11g

Objective is to generate report by collecting data from multiple systems.

Inventory system : This systems provides view and a dblink is created to this systems database.

Order system : This systems provides web services to return data in XML format.

reporting system: Here is where the report will be initiated and generated this is a webservice called from WebUI.

Logic :

From the reporting system WS we call the Order system , this will return a chunk of data ( can be very large but only three fields )in xml format.

Create a temporary table and insert all the data from XML in to it.

Join the Inventory system view and temporary data to fetch all the required data and send to reporting system.

Questions :

How do i create temp table in java?

How do I convert XML to sql data and insert in temp table ?

Answer (score 0):

As I see the problem, I would parse the XML with one of the [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) and would create an array for the table. If the fields aren't Strings, one posibility can be to create objects that take the XML value as constructor.

Comment: I agree, but I remember reading it somewhere on this SO that sql data can be converted to XML directly. This will avoid parsing and inserting the rows.