# How to parse response as xml

Tags: xml, google-app-engine

I am using URL Fetch service on GAE for java and the response is returning of type XML like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<stories type="array" count="0" total="0" filter="'blawblaw'">
</stories>
```

I can print it as string like

```
log.info(new String(response.getContent(),"UTF-8"));
```

But, converting it as String is not the right thing here as i need to read story count and then story under it. Please advise how to do that on GAE

Comment: How about parsing the XML? https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Comment: what i am getting is XML not the json and the library seems to be to convert json to java objects

Comment: Sorry about that - my mistake. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: does it play nice with google app engine?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Peter's response of reference [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) helped me getting it. I finally used a SAX parser which is supported on google app engine