# How to get individual attribute from the XML file in a simpler way

Tags: java, xml, parsing, servlets

I am trying to send XML file to one of my Servlet class and I am able to do that. Below is my XML file-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<request id="a487bd863c3e4513a7893966f8e186f1">
<app hash="sha1"/>
</request>
```

And following is my `Servlet doPost` method in which I need to parse the XML file and get `id and hash value` from that XML file.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String line;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(request.getReader());
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            // now here parse the line and get `id and hash value`
            // from it.
        }
    }
```

I am thinking what is the best way to get id and hash value from that XML file. I know one way is to parse the XML file and get the id and hash value. Is there any easy or direct way to get what I am looking for?

Any simple example will be appreciated.

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try [XPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/xpath/XPath.html)

```
    XPathFactory xPathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xPath = xPathFactory.newXPath();
    String id = xPath.evaluate("/request/@id",
            new InputSource(request.getInputStream()));
```

If you need both id and hash then

```
    InputStream is = request.getInputStream();
    Document doc = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
            .newDocumentBuilder().parse(is);
    String id = ((Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("request").item(0))
            .getAttribute("id");
    String hash = ((Element) doc.getElementsByTagName("app").item(0))
            .getAttribute("hash");
```

since parsers close `InpuStream` we need to prevent it

```
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(request.getInputStream()) {
        public void close() {
        }
    };
```

Comment: Thanks Evgeniy for the suggestion. And what about hash? I need to pull that as well from the XML.

Comment: If I am doing like this after String id line - `String hash = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("/app/@hash", new InputSource(request.getInputStream()));`. I am getting stream closed exception

Comment: you have to read completely and buffer `request.getInputStream()` in memory or disk and then use it. Request stream over HTTP socket can't be read back again.

Comment: @BimaleshJha, Thanks for suggestion. Can you provide a simple example?

Comment: @akirahin3 check this snippet: 
ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream(); //in memory, assuming small data
IOUtils.copy(request.getInputStream, bytes); //using apache commons IOUtils
//use InputSource on in memory buffer in XPath API
new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes.toByteArray()));

Answer (score 1):

You can use [sax parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/) or [dom parser](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/) to parse xml file.