# Represent XML in java object

Tags: java, xml, mapping

I have a xml file and I want to represent it in java objects in best way (using the best data structures.) What is the best architecture for it.

Ex:

```
<Parent>
<child1 par=aaa par2=bbb>
<userName>xxx</userName>
<password>xxx</password>

</child1>

<child2>
<child22>

---------

</child22>
</child2>
</parent>
```

Here how do I manage the java classes  and variable ?

Comment: Take a look at XStream, it's an easy solution for your problem.

Comment: Take a look at Java Architecture for XML Binding (JAXB) http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is what [JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/) was born for.  It's the built-in Java object-to-XML binding API.

Answer (score 0):

There's plenty of information readily available on Java XML parsers.  Check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java?lq=1) for some great discussion and recommendations.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Parent {
    // List containing child class objects
    List<child> childList = new ArrayList<child>();

    getChildList(){}
    setChildList(){}

}

Class Child {
    String username;
    String password;

    //getter/setters for username and password.//
}
```

The **child** class contains 2 strings to represent "username" and "password". This class represents the **child** node in the given xml.

The **parent** class contains a list of **child** class objects. This class represents the **parent** tag in the xml and list of **child** class objects is for the **child** nodes in the xml.

The XML can be parsed and the values for each node can be stored using the above architecture.

Alternatively,  **JAXB** can be used to automate this conversion from XML to JAVA objects.

Comment: Flagged up in the lqp queue.  Your answer needs to be fleshed out to minimally include an explanation of what your code is doing and how it solves the op's question.  Code only answers are likely to attract down votes and possibly even close votes.  Please use 'edit' to bring your answer into a context where readers can profit from it.