# Reading specific strings from XML tags

Tags: java

I am using java, I want to read strings from an XML tag. EX: < blank type="Something">
I need to be able to assign "Something" to a variable. Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like you want an XML parser. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: You are not likely to get an answer unless you post the code you have written as an attempt to solve the problem. We're not writing it for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to do this:

- You can use the XML APIs provided with Java (SAX or STAX or DOM).
- There are libraries that build on the XML APIs (JDOM, DOM4J, or XOM) which are easier to use than the raw APIs.
- There's Java-XML databinding, described in [Pratik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19279205/217324). Java-XML databinding is sometimes overkill, depending on your requirements, and when there are errors they can be hard to figure out. Sometimes it's worthwhile, though. I think JiBX is particularly interesting.

If you don't know where to start, start with [XOM](http://xom.nu/). XOM was created by a JDOM contributor, it was designed to be easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to achieve is referred to as **Unmarshalling** an XML. **Unmarshalling** means extracting data from an XML document and using it to construct a Java object or graph of objects. There are various APIs available to do the same. You should have a look at the following links:

- JAXB:
  http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-140168.html
- Castor: http://castor.codehaus.org/
- JiBX: http://jibx.sourceforge.net/