# OpenSearch Compatible Response From Java

Tags: java, opensearch

Here is an example OpenSearch description file:

```
http://webcat.hud.ac.uk/OpenSearch.xml
```

When I send a query as like that:

```
http://webcat.hud.ac.uk/perl/opensearch.pl?keyword=new&startpage=1&itemsperpage=20
```

I get a response which is compatible to OpenSearch. How can I implement OpenSearch specification at Java or is there any library for it or is there any xsd that I can generate a Java code from it?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [OpenSearch website](http://www.opensearch.org/Community/OpenSearch_software)'s section on *"Reading OpenSearch"*, there is a Java library which can do this, called [Apache Abdera](http://abdera.apache.org/). I have not used it myself, so I cannot comment on its quality, but it should be worth looking into - apparently it can both interpret AND create OpenSearch responses, so this may be exactly what you're looking for.

Alternatively, there are quite a few very good XML parsers for Java (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) for some suggestions), so writing your own parser for a simple OpenSearch XML file shouldn't be *too* difficult, since the [full specification](http://www.opensearch.org/Specifications/OpenSearch/1.1) is available online.

As for an XSD, I can't find an "official" one, however there are XSD's for OpenSearch in various open source projects which have been tested and you can use, such as [this one](http://opensearchvalidator.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#TathamOddie.OpenSearchValidator.Logic/Resources/OpenSearchDescription.xsd), which is part of a project called "OpenSearch Validator."

Another potential choice for writing OpenSearch results is the very mature and widely-used [Apache Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/) library, which is in the list of software "writing OpenSearch results" in the previously linked OpenSearch website.

Comment: I want to generate OpenSearch standard responses.

Comment: Did you even look at the link to Abdera? It has the capability to generate OpenSearch results as well (requires an extra add-on module to do so).

Comment: Is there anything I can do to improve this answer? You ask for "a detailed working answer," and I think I've provided numerous solutions to software which will work for you. I'd love to add more detail, if you let me know what you're looking for!

Comment: Just some things: I think that I can use XSL to generate such responses? What should I include at a response (HTML, Atom, RSS) to say that "I support Opensearch type responses"?

Comment: XSL(T) is pretty general; you could use it to write responses in one format and then transform them into OpenSearch XML, or you could use them to render OpenSearch XML as a human-readable HTML page, or etc. As for letting clients know that you can speak in OpenSearch, that is probably really dependent on what clients are talking to you. From what I have read, OpenSearch is generally used to implement search APIs, so your clients should already know before trying to talk to you.

Answer (score 0):

[ROME](http://github.com/rometools/) also supports OpenSearch with its [ROME Module A9 OpenSearch](http://rometools.github.io/rome-modules/A9OpenSearch.html).

Sample usage:

```
SyndFeed feed = new SyndFeedImpl();
feed.setFeedType(feedType);

// Add the opensearch module, you would get information like totalResults from the
// return results of your search
List mods = feed.getModules();
OpenSearchModule osm = new OpenSearchModuleImpl();
osm.setItemsPerPage(1);
osm.setStartIndex(1);
osm.setTotalResults(1024);
osm.setItemsPerPage(50);

OSQuery query = new OSQuery();
query.setRole("superset");
query.setSearchTerms("Java Syndication");
query.setStartPage(1);
osm.addQuery(query);

Link link = new Link();
link.setHref("http://www.bargainstriker.com/opensearch-description.xml");
link.setType("application/opensearchdescription+xml");
osm.setLink(link);

mods.add(osm);

feed.setModules(mods);
// end add module
```