# Understanding and XML file in Java

Tags: java, xml

I am working on a project where I need to read in an XML file and use the information in the file to analyze user input.  More specifically the file looks like this.

```
<course>
<category  name="Course Name">
    <category name="Exams">
        <item name="Midterm" outof="110.0" weight="17.0"></item>
        <item name="Final Exam" outof="110.0" weight="18.0"></item>
    </category>

    <category name="Individual Assignments">
            <item name="Swing GUI Conference Program" outof="50.0" weight="7.5">     </item>
            <item name="Assignment 2" outof="50.0" weight="7.5">     </item>
            <item name="Assignment 3" outof="50.0" weight="7.5">     </item>
            <item name="Assignment 4" outof="50.0" weight="7.5">     </item>

    </category>

    <category name="Group Projects">
        <item name="Lab Selector Project" outof="75.0" weight="15"></item>
        <item name="Android Project" outof="75.0" weight="15"></item>
    </category>

    <category name="Homework, Quizzes, Participation">
        <item name="01 - GUI Using Dialog Boxes" outof="20.0" weight="2.5"></item>
        <item name="02 - GUID Using Menu Files" outof="20.0" weight="2.5"></item>
    </category> 

</category>
```

What I need to be able to do is pull this information so that I can use it in a grade calcualtor application.

Edit: Several of you have mentions SAX/DOM editor and I've searched and tried both of those methods but when I try to implement them it comes back will blank strings.  I think it has to do with all the examples I find looking like this:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school>
 <student id="1">
  <firstname>ankush</firstname>
  <lastname>thakur</lastname>
  <email>beingjavaguy.gmail.com</email>
  <phone>7678767656</phone>
 </student>
 <student id="2">
  <firstname>aarti</firstname>
  <lastname>gupta</lastname>
  <email>aartigupta.gmail.com</email>
  <phone>9876546545</phone>
 </student>
</school>
```

Whereas my xml file has all the information stored in the opening tag and not stored in between the open and close tags.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: Use JDom. Its easier than others.

Comment: [Parse the XML](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/).  If you need to be able to re-iterate over the contents, parse it into a DOM and use XPath, otherwise you can use a SAX style parser...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a XML parser like sax or DOM to parse the xml to your java program and then can work on the implementation the calc.

[how to use sax and DOM](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2002/06/26/xml.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you have XSD for this XML (or can write), you can use JAXB for avoid writing parsing code , and get XML data as Java POJO with "unmarshal".

Comment: +1 - a With JAXB you can also start from POJOs using annotations to control the mapping to XML.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out the SAX parser.  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-sax-parser/.  If you have a more specific question I'm sure we could help you better

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the XML with parsers like SAX or DOM or StAX are helpful to fetch the information you want. See this link for basic example : [Parsing xml using DOM, SAX and StAX](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/05/parsing-xml-using-dom-sax-and-stax-parser-in-java.html)