# Extracting information from XML File

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, xml, servlets

I have been trying to extract the information from this file for the past couple of hours and have run out of options.

http://www.nationalbanken.dk/dndk/valuta.nsf/valuta-hist.xml

Currently I have the information stored as a string in a Java servlet.

When I try to send it as a response to an AJAX request, I can't seem to extract any of the attributes through jQuery (mainly the time, currency, etc.)

I don't have a whole lot of experience with XML, actually none, so after trying various methods here on StackOverflow I have come to the conclusion that I simply can't find anything that'll work for me.

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "AjaxController?command=currency",
        cache: false,
        dataType: "xml",
        success: processXML
    });
});
```

This is my AJAX call to the servlet, in return it gives back the file linked above loaded into a string, which then needs to be processed and extracted by the jQuery function "processXML".

Comment: So what is your question? How to parse XML-data in jQUery function? Or what?

Comment: You want to parse/access xml using jquery? or you are getting problem with response?

Comment: The problem I have is that because of the way the xml is formatted, I cant seem to gain access to the attributes and their values.

I can get the "Aktuelle Valutakurser" and "National Banken" things that are in plain text but everything else just comes out as undefined everytime I try to do anything with it.

If I just do alert(data) it will show the entire xml file but I am not able to do anything with it.

Comment: I think that this could be useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: One of the solutions might be the this: [How to Parse XML File using XPath in Java](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/)