# How to get data the given xml file corresponding to notes,totalqtypctmin,totalqtypctmax,mismatchthresholdpct,prodgrp,prodid,locgroup,geoid?

Tags: java, xml, jakarta-ee, rft

```
<pko:POImport xmlns:xs="http://XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:pko="hello"
xs:schemaLocation=" PlannedQuantityImport.xsd" tag="TAG" notes="These are my notes" totalqtypctmin="2" totalqtypctmax="3" mismatchthresholdpct="8.0">
  <prodgrp id="100067">
    <prodid>SYC87948427320</prodid>
    <locgrp id="100067">
      <geoid>30454</geoid>
      <geoid>30982</geoid>
      <quantity date="2010-12-11" sequence="1" prodid="87948427320">600</quantity>
    </locgrp>
  </prodgrp>
</pko:POImport>
```

I want to get the data corresponding to

**tag, notes,totalqtypctmin,totalqtypctmax,mismatchthresholdpct,prodgrp,prodid,locgroup,geoid** etc.

Comment: `I have an xml file` -- This ain't a __question__ title, is it?

Answer (score 1):

You will need XML parser to extract information from a XML using your desired xPath. Refer to this [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java).

Answer (score 1):

I'd just use string matching.

```
inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.xml"));
while(inputStream.hasNext()){
    String s=inputStream.next();
    if(s.indexOf("totalqtypctmax")==-1)
        continue;
    String k = s.split("totalqtypctmax=\"")[1].split("\"")[0];
    System.out.println("The value of totalqtypctmax is "+k);
}
```

Java isn't my first language, so pardon any silly mistakes.

EDIT: The only reason I'm using string matching instead of a standard XML parser, which is obviously recommended for more elaborate XML files, is because, in this case, your requirements seem very specific.

Answer (score 0):

Their are various methods for parsing in java you could either use

- DOM parsing
- SAX parsing

These are included in the JDK by default
you can also use **JDOM**
Goto the following link to more info
http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/java-xml-tutorials/