# How do I check if an XML node is a leaf node in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I want to list of all the leaf nodes present in an XML document. The XML is not fixed, thus the code should work for any given XML file.

Comment: Which of the many Java XML API's are you using or do you want to use?

Comment: Anything is fine DOM or SAX.

Answer (score 3):

Find an XML parser. Those libraries will parse the XML String for you and build an Object Oriented tree of the XML nodes (called a DOM, which stands for Document Object Model). There should be definitely a method like `getChildCount()`, `getChildren()` or `isLeaf()`.

Take a look here: [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

Comment: Just a small nitpick: DOM parsers build a tree, SAX parsers will just fire an event every time they find something - so for OP's use case DOM is probably easier.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the DOM:

```
if (!myNode.hasChildNodes())
{
   // found a leaf node
}
```