# Read parent and child at the same time using SAX Parser in Java

Tags: java, xml, sax

I have a very small xml file, which I just want to read in Java. After referring [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/373935/1175065), I decided to go with SAX parser. My xml file looks like below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<catalog>
    <library name="Central Library">
        <read>
            <book id="001" lang="ENG" title="Operating System Concepts" author="Silberschatz" />
            <book id="002" lang="ENG" title="Design Patterns: Elements of Reusable Object-Oriented Software" author="Gangs of Four" />
        </read>
        <unread>
            <book id="003" lang="ENG" title="Introduction to Algorithms" author="Cormen" />
            <book id="004" lang="ENG" title="Computer networks" author="Tanenbaum" />
        </unread>
    </library>
</catalog>
```

While reading this xml, I am unable to identify read and unread books. 
Below is the parser code-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ParseXML extends DefaultHandler {
    private Library lib;
    public ParseXML(String file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        parse(file);
    }
    private void parse(String file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        final SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(file, this);
    }
    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("library")) {
            String name = attributes.getValue("name");
            lib = new Library(name);
        }
        if (qName.equals("book")) {
            String id = attributes.getValue("id");
            String lang = attributes.getValue("lang");
            String title = attributes.getValue("title");
            String author = attributes.getValue("author");

            Book book = new Book(id, lang, title, author);

            // How to decide here, to which list this book should be added
            lib.addIntoReadBooks(book);
            // lib.addIntoUnreadBooks(book);
        }
    }

    /**
    * @return the library
    */
    public Library getLibrary() {
        return lib;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ParseXML parseXML = new ParseXML("repository/books.xml");
            Library library = parseXML.getLibrary();

            System.out.println("Library=" + library);

            } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (SAXException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

The Library and Book class are following-

Library.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public final class Library {
    private final String name;
    private final List<Book> readBooks;
    private final List<Book> unreadBooks;

    public Library(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        readBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
        unreadBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    }

    public void addIntoReadBooks(Book book) {
        getReadBooks().add(book);
    }

    public void addIntoUnreadBooks(Book book) {
        getUnreadBooks().add(book);
    }
    //Getters
}
```

Book.java

```
public class Book {
    private final String id;
    private final String lang;
    private final String title;
    private final String author;

    public Book(String id, String lang, String title, String author) {
        this.id = id;
        this.lang = lang;
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
    //Getters
}
```

How to decide, to which list the book should be added?

## My answer

Somehow I managed to live with following code, which uses two flag to keep track of visited nodes-

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ParseXML extends DefaultHandler {

    private Library lib;
    private boolean read;
    private boolean unread;

    public ParseXML(String file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        parse(file);
    }

    private void parse(String file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        final SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(file, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("read")) {
            read = false;
        }
        if (qName.equals("unread")) {
            unread = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("library")) {
            String name = attributes.getValue("name");
            lib = new Library(name);
        }
        if (qName.equals("read")) {
            read = true;
        }
        if (qName.equals("unread")) {
            unread = true;
        }
        if (qName.equals("book")) {
            String id = attributes.getValue("id");
            String lang = attributes.getValue("lang");
            String title = attributes.getValue("title");
            String author = attributes.getValue("author");

            Book book = new Book(id, lang, title, author);

            // How to decide here, to which list this book should be added
            if (read && !unread) {
                lib.addIntoReadBooks(book);
                } else if (!read && unread) {
                lib.addIntoUnreadBooks(book);
            }
        }
    }

    /**
    * @return the lib
    */
    public Library getLibrary() {
        return lib;
    }
}
```

Is there exist any better solution for the same?

Comment: Why vote to close? I already referred in lot of places but didn't found this kind of scenario.

Comment: Why are you not indenting your code properly? This hurts to read :).

Comment: @PavelHoral: I apologize. I just copy and pasted from Eclipse.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about solving an issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear to me that this is necessarily better, but you could maintain a `currentList` field in your `ParseXML` class for the current list to manipulate:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;
import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

public class ParseXML extends DefaultHandler {

    private Library lib;
    private List<Book> extraBooks = new ArrayList<Book>();
    private List<Book> currentList = extraBooks;

    public ParseXML(String file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        parse(file);
    }

    private void parse(String file) throws ParserConfigurationException, SAXException, IOException {
        final SAXParserFactory factory = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        final SAXParser parser = factory.newSAXParser();
        parser.parse(file, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("read") || qName.equals("unread"))
            currentList = extraBooks;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes attributes) throws SAXException {
        if (qName.equals("library")) {
            String name = attributes.getValue("name");
            lib = new Library(name);
        }
        else if (qName.equals("read")) {
            currentList = lib.getReadBooks();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("unread")) {
            currentList = lib.getUnreadBooks();
        }
        else if (qName.equals("book")) {
            String id = attributes.getValue("id");
            String lang = attributes.getValue("lang");
            String title = attributes.getValue("title");
            String author = attributes.getValue("author");

            currentList.add(new Book(id, lang, title, author));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the lib
     */
    public Library getLibrary() {
        return lib;
    }

}
```

As a mildly different approach, you could of course keep both lists and the library name as fields in your handler, and create the `Library` in the `endElement` method using all the data collected.

Note: (obsolete) In this code I used the field `extraBooks` to allow for `<book>` tags occurring outside the `<read>` and `<unread>` tags.  It's just a little safer than just setting `currentList` to `null` in the `endElement` method.  I hate `NullPointerException`.

**Update:**

You don't need the throwaway field `extraBooks`.

You can accomplish the same null-safety by changing the initialization of `currentList` to

```
private List<Book> currentList = new ArrayList<Book>();
```

and the `endElement` method to

```
@Override
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {
    if (qName.equals("read") || qName.equals("unread"))
        currentList = new ArrayList<Book>();
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got one more approach using `XMLReader` with SAX . It has a functionality of setting `ContentHandler`. Thank you very much.