# Unmarshall raw schema-less XML

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

I have an InputStream of data in the XML format.  There is no schema; any valid XML could be given to my application.  I want to do things like count nodes, calculate attribute frequencies at different levels, etc.

I want to be able to unmarshall the XML into something I can work with in Java.  The amount of data is relatively small (100MBs) so I'm not worried about loading it all at once into memory.  Everything I read about Jaxb is telling me I need to generate java classes which the data maps directly to.  But I have no idea what the data will look like; all I know is that it's XML.

Is there a "raw" unmarshal functionality when I can get some sort of nested map structure, and then "walk around" the XML document myself?

Comment: You can't unmarshall random XML - what would it unmarshall into exactly? You you need to use [JAXP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_API_for_XML_Processing) not JAXB. Read the XML into a [`Document`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/Document.html).

Comment: @BoristheSpider Perfect; I think my misconception was the definition of the word "unmarshall".  If that's the answer I will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Avoid using non-standard methods](https://stackoverflow.com/a/373935/34880) such as JDOM. As already stated by comments you can not un-marshall your XML since you do not know what can be inside. Roughly an XML element translates to a class member, so if you do not know in advance the possible element (tag) names it is impossible you can define a class with JAXB annotations that can be translated back an forth from XML.

In your case to count nodes and attributes I would use SAX processing. You can write an easy SAX Handler to just count them (even create a Hashmap with different counters for each element/attribute name, I do not know your exact needs).

The "raw" tree structure is exactly a DOM tree (other standard way of processing XML).

Answer (score 0):

You can of course use JAXP and parse the XML into a [Document](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html), but you'll be a lot more productive using a more Java friendly API like [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/).