# Split XML String in Java into 3 parts

Tags: java, xml, string, split

I have the following XML stored in a String

```
<MessageHeader>
<MessageThreadId>201401140942060</MessageThreadId>
</MessageHeader>
<MessageNotificationPeriod>
<StartDate>2013-11-01T00:00:00.000000</StartDate>
<EndDate>2013-12-01T00:00:00.000000</EndDate>
</MessageNotificationPeriod>
<SalesReport>
<SalesByTerritory>
<TerritoryCode>US</TerritoryCode>
</SalesByTerritory>
</SalesByCommercialModel>
</SalesReport>
```

I want to split the string into 3 parts so that it can be printed at different places in the file I will be creating. I want `</MessageNotificationPeriod>` to end the first part, `</TerritoryCode>` to end the second part and the remaining to be in the third new string. I've tried to use String.split() but it removes the string I am splitting at.

Comment: You should consider to use an XML Parser instead of string splitting, check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java

Comment: There's technical reasons for creating the file in this way based on how the data(SalesByTerritory) is coming from the database.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to parse the XML, it's easy enough to use a regex:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(
    "^(.*</MessageNotificationPeriod>)(.*</TerritoryCode>)(.*)$"
);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(xmlString);
if (!matcher.matches()) { 
   throw new IllegalStateException();
}
String part1 = matcher.group(1);
String part2 = matcher.group(2);
String part3 = matcher.group(3);
```

See the [capturing groups tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)

Answer (score -1):

did you try subString(start, end) method