# How I can get all values from particular tag in XML?

Tags: java, xml

I have `file.xml` i need extract with java all values from `<command>` tag:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
<command> com1 </command>
<result> res1 </result>
<command> com2 </command>
<result> res2 </result>
</config>
```

May be it exists some methods to extract this values to ArrayList?

Comment: use Xpath  http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

Comment: You need to use an XML parser. Try to read this article: http://javarevisited.blogspot.se/2011/12/parse-xml-file-in-java-example-tutorial.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPATH is a good option. Please check below code, it could help you

```
    DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder builder =  factory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = builder.parse("test.xml");

    XPathFactory xFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xFactory.newXPath();
    XPathExpression  expr = xpath.compile("//command/text()");
    Object result = expr.evaluate(doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);

    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
    for (int i=0; i<nodes.getLength();i++){
      System.out.println(nodes.item(i).getNodeValue());
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple xml parser topic on stackoverflow : [Stack link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)

And I would encourage you to look at this tutorial : [Xml parsing tut](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaXML/article.html)

Answer (score 1):

Use [simple-xml](http://simple.sourceforge.net/):

`Config.java`:

```
import java.util.List;
import org.simpleframework.xml.ElementList;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Root;

@Root
public class Config {

    @ElementList(entry = "result", inline = true)
    List<String> results;
    @ElementList(entry = "command", inline = true)
    List<String> commands;

    public List<String> getResults() {
        return results;
    }

    public void setResults(List<String> results) {
        this.results = results;
    }

    public List<String> getCommands() {
        return commands;
    }

    public void setCommands(List<String> commands) {
        this.commands = commands;
    }

}
```

`App.java`

```
import java.io.InputStream;
import org.simpleframework.xml.Serializer;
import org.simpleframework.xml.core.Persister;
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        InputStream is = App.class.getResourceAsStream("config.xml");

        Serializer serializer = new Persister();
        Config config = serializer.read(Config.class, is);

        for (String command : config.getCommands()) {
            System.out.println("command=" + command);
        }
    }
}
```