# Retrieve a certain element in XML

Tags: xml, dom, rss

Is it possible to get certain elements in an RSS feed with java. Right now i am trying to extract the specific weather condition off an RSS feed (yahoo)

Assuming the XML as below

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes" ?>
<rss version="2.0" xmlns:yweather="http://xml.weather.yahoo.com/ns/rss/1.0" xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
<channel>
  <title>Yahoo! Weather - Sunnyvale, CA</title>
  <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html</link>
  <description>Yahoo! Weather for Sunnyvale, CA</description>
  <language>en-us</language>
  <lastBuildDate>Fri, 18 Dec 2009 9:38 am PST</lastBuildDate>
  <ttl>60</ttl>
  <yweather:location city="Sunnyvale" region="CA"   country="United States"/>
  <yweather:units temperature="F" distance="mi" pressure="in" speed="mph"/>
  <yweather:wind chill="50"   direction="0"   speed="0" />
  <yweather:atmosphere humidity="94"  visibility="3"  pressure="30.27"  rising="1" />
  <yweather:astronomy sunrise="7:17 am"   sunset="4:52 pm"/>
  <image>
    <title>Yahoo! Weather</title>
    <width>142</width>
    <height>18</height>
    <link>http://weather.yahoo.com</link>
    <url>http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/nws/th/main_142b.gif</url>
  </image>
  <item>
    <title>Conditions for Sunnyvale, CA at 9:38 am PST</title>
    <geo:lat>37.37</geo:lat>
    <geo:long>-122.04</geo:long>
    <link>http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html</link>
    <pubDate>Fri, 18 Dec 2009 9:38 am PST</pubDate>
    <yweather:condition  text="Mostly Cloudy"  code="28"  temp="50"  date="Fri, 18 Dec 2009 9:38 am PST" />
    <description><![CDATA[
<img src="http://l.yimg.com/a/i/us/we/52/28.gif"/><br />
<b>Current Conditions:</b><br />
Mostly Cloudy, 50 F<BR />
<BR /><b>Forecast:</b><BR />
Fri - Partly Cloudy. High: 62 Low: 49<br />
Sat - Partly Cloudy. High: 65 Low: 49<br />
<br />
<a href="http://us.rd.yahoo.com/dailynews/rss/weather/Sunnyvale__CA/*http://weather.yahoo.com/forecast/USCA1116_f.html">Full Forecast at Yahoo! Weather</a><BR/><BR/>
(provided by <a href="http://www.weather.com" >The Weather Channel</a>)<br/>
]]></description>
    <yweather:forecast day="Fri" date="18 Dec 2009" low="49" high="62" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30" />
    <yweather:forecast day="Sat" date="19 Dec 2009" low="49" high="65" text="Partly Cloudy" code="30" />
    <guid isPermaLink="false">USCA1116_2009_12_18_9_38_PST</guid>
  </item>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Can i get the elements yweather:atmosphere humidity="94"?  This does not seem like an elegant way to do it. Is there a better way?

EDIT: What i am trying at the moment is try and get the attributes out

```
NodeList items = doc.getElementsByTagName(""); 
Element item = (Element)items.item(0); 
for (int i = 0; i < items.getLength(); i++) {                
    Node node = items.item(i);

    if (node.hasAttributes()) {
        Attr attr = (Attr) node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("type");
        if (attr != null) {
            String attribute= attr.getValue();                      
            System.out.println("attribute: " + attribute);                      
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What you're looking for is an [XML parser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java). There are many.

Comment: Im already doing using DocumentBuilder to parse it into a document

Comment: Well, if you have a DOM Document, why are you trying to parse the text version as a string? Can we see your code, please? It would help to know what you're trying at the moment.

Comment: Sorry mate. Just updated the first page with my code. Im trying to extract out the attribute values