# Search for a value in XML

Tags: java, xml

What is the best way to do a search in XML  ?

Basically in need to find the “DN” value = “dina.net”

This is the XML:

```
  <UD>
    <node status="15" name="DINA" KEY="340557#200055465" parentNodePK="">
       <attr name="UDID" value="340557" />
       <attr name="version" value="" DMID="6115"/>
       <attr name="DN" value="dina.net" UDMID="6118"/>
    </node>
    <node status="1500210002" name=" DINA@0" KEY="340557#200055466" parentNodePK="340557#200055465">
      <attr name=" UDID " value="340557"/>
      <attr name="version" value="" DMID="6125"/>
    </node>
 </UD>
```

Thanks

Comment: I mean, can you count on the `attr name` always being "DN", or is there other data you want to extract? If it's the former, then a specific solution (i.e. some simple string parsing) is the way to go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different XML libraries for Java out there utilizing different methods from DOM, SAX, etc.   Depending on your use, you can even map them to objects utilizing a library like Jackson.

For just reading XML, here is a good review:
[Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)