# How to get value within an xml tag using java code

Tags: java, xml

I have a String variable in java with xml tags as its value:

eg: String xml="<root><name>abcd</name><age>22</age><gender>male</gender></root>";

Now I need to get the value within the name tag i.e "abcd" from this variable and store the value in another string variable. How to go about this using java. Can anyone please help me out with this?

Comment: The one line of code you posted isn't even valid Java code.  How do you expect us to help you?

Comment: post your java code tried so far!!!!

Answer (score 1):

It is not quite clear what you want, but I think what you will need is something to read an XML document (as a file or directly as a string), an XML parser.

There is a whole list (and many more) of different XML parsers you can use for this:

- [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/)
- [Woodstox](http://woodstox.codehaus.org/)
- [XOM](http://xom.nu/)
- [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [VTD-XML](http://vtd-xml.sourceforge.net/)
- [Xerces-J](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-j/)
- [Crimson](http://xml.apache.org/crimson/)

I would recommend [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) for its easy usage. Here is an example for a [dom4j](http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/) implemenation:

```
String xmlPath = "myXmlDocument.xml";

SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = reader.read(xmlPath);
Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
System.out.println("Root Element: "+rootElement.getName());
```

You can directly feed in a String to be parsed to an XML document too:

```
String xmlString = "<name>Hello</name>";

SAXReader reader = new SAXReader();
Document document = DocumentHelper.parseText(xmlString);
Element rootElement = document.getRootElement();
System.out.println("Root Element: "+rootElement.getName());
```

**References**

- [Best XML parser for Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java)
- http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/dom4j-1.6.1/faq.html#from-string

Comment: Thanks for the info but I need to find the value based on tag names. eg: 22 for age tag. How do I achieve this. Please help me out with this.