# How to read multiple hierarchy nodes and values of XML in Java?

Tags: java, xml

I am writing a program in Java where I have to traverse through nodes and return the output value of an attribute of XML string.

How do I traverse through the path to get a attribute value in Java.

Comment: First step would be to use an XML library ([here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/373833/best-xml-parser-for-java) for example) and find the node you want to access, and then get its attribute value.

Comment: Try googling for xpath.

Answer (score 0):

Try this here:

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/dom/readingXML.html

at

Node Operations
- Traversing nodes